# What are the best ways to find answers that should be flagged or edited?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've been experimenting with the flagging system for the last couple of days. I have learned a few strategies, but I feel that I'm making little difference to the mountain of accumulated rubbish.

Having easily run out of my 48 flags within a few minutes tonight, I am now helpless for another 19 hours and thought I would share a couple of tips for finding likely posts to flag with the rest of you, to help keep our poor moderators busy and entertained.

1. The simplest: Look at the [first posts of new users](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?pagesize=15&filter=all). Apart from general scanning, if they have a negative score, they're very likely to be comments or question updates.
2. Search: [body:"same problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22same+problem%22). This finds bucketloads of "Me too!! Any progress?" answers.
3. Search: [body:bump](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:bump). Gets lots of thread-bumping non-answers.

A couple of thoughts:

- If there was a way to search only within answers, not questions, then other searches, like 'update', to find updates posted as answers, would probably be effective.
- If it was possible to add regex matches like start of line (^), then searches like 'bump' would be much more effective.

Please post any other ideas you have found that make finding detritus easier. There's more than enough junk out there for everyone... Anything we can do to make it easier to spot improves the editing efficiency of the collective.

Comment: If there's a query for non-accepted answers posted by OPs, I'd imagine it would be helpful. There are lots of answers posted by OPs who are unaware of the edit and/or comment features of the site.

Comment: per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/ we actually detect a lot of these 'answers' and force the answerer to click through a EULA when we do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer -- latest stats Answer Eulas Invoked: 20834 | Answer Eulas Ignored: 9793

Comment: +1 more than doubled my flag weight today thanks to these tips :)

Comment: Well, this post explains a lot...

Comment: +1 my flag weight went up by almost a factor of 3.14 today thanks to these tips (which is appropriate, given today is π day)

Comment: Hopefully my ten submissions helped out, amazing how quickly you can burn through those. I'd upvote this, but need more rep on meta first. :)

Comment: @Bill: It also explains what's happening to the [alots](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html).

Comment: @Jason: I tried to ask for such a query, but got no answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84538/can-i-search-for-answers-by-the-op

Answer (score 44):

This is more for laughs than anything else, and doesn't really answer your question, since they are more candidates for editing than flagging, but here goes:

- With this many questions, we have a great deal of misspelling. For example:

  - [dinamically (5,566)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dinamically)
  - [choosen (5,636)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=choosen)
  - [facebok (221)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebok), [facbook (303)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facbook), [faebook (17)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=faebook)
  - [cant (220k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cant), [doest (1,710)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=doest), [aint (1,903)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aint), [wont (106k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wont), [wouldnt (5,587)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wouldnt)
  - [jqury (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jqury), [jqueery (0)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jqueery), [jquey (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquey), [jqery (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jqery)
  - [javscript (3,086)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javscript)
  - [sqllite (4,780)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqllite)
  - [goggle (1,421)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=goggle)
  - [teh (8,400+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=teh)
  - [proble (1,341)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=proble) and [problam (308)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=problam)
  - [datbase (1,200+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datbase)
  - [recieve (33k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recieve)
  - [acheive (27k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=acheive)
  - [definately (3,430)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=definately)
  - [wierd (6,300+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wierd)
  - [framwork (2,600+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=framwork) and [libray (1,481)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=libray)
  - [firfox (373)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firfox), [firefo (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefo), [frefox (14)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=frefox) and [chrom (1,510)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chrom), [crhome (83)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crhome), [crome (765)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crome)
- We also have a lot of ["alot"s](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) - [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alot) **More than 32,000!**
- And a great many **SOLVED!!!** questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Asolved
- We are very suggestive: [try this (682k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22try+this%22) and [check this (141k)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22check+this%22)
- Some users like to be friendly!

  - [hey guys (9,300+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22hey+guys%22)
  - [dear friends (330)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22dear+friends%22)
  - [sir (3,309)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:sir)
  - [thanks (**2.9M!!**)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:thanks) (and [tanks (1,512)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:tanks))
  - [good morning (5,100+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22good+morning%22), [good afternoon (4,200+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=good+afternoon) and [good evening (2,500+)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22good+evening%22)

> #### Pro tip: if you have less than 2k rep, go edit these posts, or better yet, build a bot to edit these posts, for massive rep gain!

And for hardcore editors, if you want to somewhere to start, go append `views:1000` to those search terms for the posts receiving Google visitors. These posts should receive the most attention.

Comment: Ah, if only we could detect "loose", though. I imagine the number of misfires greatly outweighs both its number of correct uses *and* most of the ones listed here.

Comment: @GraceNote I'd wish for a case-sensitive search. Then I would be able to find my personal favourites - JQuery, jquery, html, javascript, etc...

Comment: @YiJiang +1 for the tanks!

Comment: Also, "definately" and "wierd" are good "possibly needs edited" indicators, along with lots of others, I'm sure.

Comment: *Pro tip: if you have less than 2k rep, go edit these posts...* My only caveat would be that single typo changes on their own are not helpful - see [Should tiny edits be accepted or rejected in review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review)

Comment: @ire_and_curses I personally would *love* to see less alots here. Somehow the population just went out of control, and now we have some serious problems culling them. Seriously though, most of the time there's more than one typo/spelling error to be made here - esp. those posts with 'friendly remarks'

Comment: @GraceNote "loosing" is a runner-up.

Comment: Somebody should flag this answer. Should be a comment in my eyes.

Comment: I just noticed [you](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2254368/revisions) culling the [alots](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html). How could you be killing such beautiful creatures!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The conservation efforts went *too* well! Now our ecosystem is struggling under the load of all the alots pooping on our beautiful questions, so something must be done, quickly, before a lot of alot poop clog up the systems

Comment: you could also add "FIXED!!!" in addition to "SOLVED!!" @YiJang

Comment: While we're at it, can someone cull thankyou in instances where the sentence isn't referring to a thankyou card.

Comment: Is there any way to find "too localized" questions?

Comment: After having gone on editing sprees on some sites where I wanted to build up reputation for a bot account, I would recommend two things: prefer editing relatively new questions over old ones, and try to keep the volume of edits down on low-traffic sites. In chat, @rene suggests examining the site's front page to get a sense of the recent average number of new questions per day, and staying significantly below that number, so as to avoid littering the site's front page with old content.

Comment: An alternative, in some sense less disruptive approach is to propose new tag descriptions, but that's obviously more work, and requires knowledge of the related domains.

Answer (score 28):

For the search results to contain only answers, add `isaccepted:0`, which restricts the results to non-accepted answer posts, i.e:

```
isaccepted:0 +body:"same problem"
```

Here's two more I've found useful:

[isaccepted:0 +body:"help me"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A0+%2Bbody%3A%22help+me%22)
   [isaccepted:0 +body:"plz"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted:0++body:%22plz%22)

Comment: The 'help me' search was a gold mine for non-answers.  I flagged 51 of them.

Comment: We might as well auto-delete everything @yhw42 flags ;-)

Comment: Don't assume I'm infallible @Ivo! I had one of my flags dismissed as invalid this weekend! `:)`

Comment: Wow @yhw42, a whole flag out of probably a 100! :P You had nearly 750, before they tweaked the algorithm and are already up to 621, I think I'll take the risk of you making a mistake

Comment: yhw is close to 650 now :P @Ivo.

Comment: Heh, I wonder what the highest flag weights are.

Comment: @jjnguy: When I posted this, the ["help me"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A0+%2Bbody%3A%22help+me%22) query returned `3103` results. Currently (about 4 days later) it returns `2169`. `:)`

Comment: I have to say, these are the nasty parts of the site. "Plz send me teh codes", asking for email addresses, "please read my blog entry over here then email me the answer" ... shudder. I don't normally come across that in "my" tags. Hope I helped a bit the last few days.

Comment: Also "desperate" and "bump".

Answer (score 23):

Another useful query for non-answers is `body:anyone isaccepted:0`:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3Aanyone+isaccepted%3A0

Update:

In addition to "any idea":

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22any+idea%22+isaccepted%3A0

which had a good number of non-answers (before everyone cleaned those out), another trigger phrase is "thanks in advance":

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22thanks+in+advance%22+isaccepted%3A0

Aside from when people are being quoted, the latter phrase really has no place in an answer.

Comment: I really want my "delete post" links on that page.

Comment: I'm using the 'body:somebody isaccepted:0:'.

Comment: @Tomas: Even better, try `body:"any idea" isaccepted:0`: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22any+idea%22+isaccepted%3A0

Comment: That's a goldmine!

Answer (score 17):

Random has provided a query (written by sysadmin1138) that finds answers that have a comment that includes "not an answer" at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1040/finding-bad-answers-through-comments. I would like one for "should be a comment" also. Many of the answers I am flagging today have such comments already, which were never acted on.

Edit: Having used up most of the "not an answer" and "should be a comment" I am now working through https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=isaccepted%3a0%20%2burgent%22

Edit2: in addition to **urgent**, it seems that **guys**, **cheers**, and **worked** are popular in non-answers. Also **dear** (often addressing the OP asking for teh codez), **any luck** and **any one** (just plain **anyone** is listed in another answer already.)

Came across one that puzzled me and when I searched, it has lots of siblings:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22does+not+meet+our+quality+standards%22
Unbelievable. They get around the quality filter by pasting in the actual error message.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1040/finding-bad-answers-through-comments

Comment: +1, except this is not an answer and should be a comment... :)

Comment: :-) @Zach you're right but I have a plan about that.

Comment: It was written by sysadmin1138 but if you tweak the query you can get all sorts of other comments to come back

Comment: Whew... 40 flags gone

Comment: @Kate: The comments and edits that have been accompanying your flags on SO lately have been *enormously* helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @Bill thanks for letting me know, much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

[Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?pagesize=15&filter=all) usually have a lot of "This doesn't work for me" and "Thanks this works" answers.

Can find some spam in there also sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

### Reputation-Related Commentary

- [`is:answer isaccepted:0 body:"post comments"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0+body%3A%22post+comments%22)

  Many people are strangely forthright about the fact that they should have posted a comment.
- [`is:answer accepted:0 body:"please upvote me"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+accepted%3A0+body%3A%22please+upvote+me%22)
- [`is:answer accepted:0 body:"please upvote my"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+accepted%3A0+body%3A%22please+upvote+my%22)

  People shouldn't beg for upvotes in their answers.
- [`is:answer accepted:0 body:"enough rep"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+accepted%3A0+body%3A%22enough+rep%22) (*265* results!)

  **People *really* shouldn't be talking about how much reputation they have (or need) in their answers!**

### Follow-Up "Questions" and Duplicates

- [`is:answer isaccepted:0 body:"have another question"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0+body%3A%22have+another+question%22)

  This gives a surprising number of "answers".
- [`is:answer body:"same question"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22same+question%22)

  Answers with the phrase "same question" are often simply pointing out duplicates and should be comments instead.

### Miscellaneous

- [`is:answer body:"Does anyone"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22Does+anyone%22)

  This really shouldn't be in an answer unless it's quoting the original question or is a link to another question on Stack Overflow.
- [`is:answer body:"appreciate it"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22appreciate+it%22)

  This isn't as consistent as searching for "Does anyone", but I'd say that about 1 in 4 hits is still not an answer.
- [`is:answer isaccepted:0 body:"I'm sorry"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0+body%3A%22I%27m+sorry%22)

  For some strange reason, people also like to apologize a lot.

Comment: The System seems to automatically detect many of these and consequently put the post into the Very Low Quality review queue.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to find quite a few using [`is:answer body:"one more question"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22one+more+question%22&submit=search).

This is often an answer that should be a new question, especially if it also contains "thanks" or similar.

I also found quite a lot of should-be comments/close votes using [`is:answer body:"this is a duplicate"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22this+is+a+duplicate%22), most of them only containing a link to the duplicate question. [`is:answer body:"duplicate" url:"*stackoverflow.com/*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3A%22duplicate%22+url%3A%22*stackoverflow.com%2F*%22) also works quite well.

Comment: ***Wow.*** I can't believe that the "duplicate" searches turn up nearly *three thousand results!*

Comment: @Chris: What strikes me as even more bizarre is that a few of them had upvotes. One even had 14 upvotes for just the single word "duplicate".

Answer (score 10):

`isaccepted:0 +body:"how can i"` helped me find plenty.

Likewise did `isaccepted:0 +body:"thanks in advance"`

Answer (score 7):

One search that seems to get a lot of posts that just link to other questions without any additional info is

[`is:answer url:"*stackoverflow.com*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20url:%22*stackoverflow.com*%22&submit=search)

Answer (score 3):

These searches mostly find old bad answers, so they are great for cleaning up the site, but within a few days enough people will have used them and flag the worse answers they show.

The danger is that lot of people will start from the first result page, and therefore the first few pages will get lots of flags, then everyone will run out of flags – so it would be better if the search results come back in random order.

(I hope the mods that cope with the flag storm this may create….)

Comment: The results on the review pages are randomized, so tip 1 is already ok with this.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: When I use some of these searches and sort by `newest` first, I get very recent posts.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting a lot from

https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=19&tab=relevance&q=body%3a%22could%20you%22%20isaccepted%3a0

As I will not have time over the next week or so to check the other 300 pages of results, someone else can get the flag weight for these.   I have been finding about 3 or 4 none answers per page of results.

(I got up to page 19, don't all start looking at page 20! choose a ramdom page to start from)

Answer (score 2):

One more: [`I would like to`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22I%20would%20like%20to%22%20is:answer). Now 4795 answers. [3738 are not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22i+would+like+to%22+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A0).

(99 are "I would like to recommend", which seems legitimate. There might some other good ones in them, too.)

Comment: Ooooh! That is such a clever idea! Very good find, I am implementing with great success.