# The Great Moderator Flag Turkey Shoot

Tags: discussion, flags

I went from flag weight 120 to flag weight 591 in a matter of hours because of the tips from this [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/easy-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-comments-for-flagging-purposes).

Flagging non-answers was great fun and I still want to keep going even though I am now all out of mod flags!   Could we perhaps have a periodic [Turkey Shoot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkey_shoot) where people with a flag weight over a certain amount get unlimited flags for the day and we can go shoot 'em up?

Comment: Somebody, I mean _somebody_ is getting me a new mouse. The left button is completely worn out.

Comment: This sounds like pure sadism. +1

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen the little orange number go over 250.

Comment: THIS IS WHY THE MOD QUEUE HAS BEEN OVER A HUNDRED FLAGS ALL FRIGGEN DAY!!!!!

Comment: @Will: Bwahahaha!

Comment: @won remember when 100 flags was a lot? Oh, memories...

Comment: I'd love to see one designated clean-up day were the whole community is encouraged to do clean up en mass for 24 hours...and then I'd like to know how long it took the mods to go through the queues.

Comment: Stupid question, but what's a flag?

Comment: @Jeff Hi from 4 years later… the situation has not improved.

Answer (score 21):

> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [pbs.org](http://www.pbs.org/marktwain/images/lmphoto_tom1.jpg))</sub>
>
> *“Like it? Well, I don’t see why I oughtn’t to like it. Does a boy get a chance to whitewash a fence every day?”*
>
> <sub>[Tom Sawyer -- Mark Twain](https://www.pbs.org/kenburns/mark-twain/)</sub>

But in all seriousness, I've spent plenty of time on the https://stackoverflow.com/review page myself, and cleaning up the questions is like picking up a bit of trash on your street -- it makes the street better for you and all your neighbors.

Note that we have

- increased the # of moderator flags available
- you get [more daily flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) as you gain more flag weight, in a virtuous cycle
- added the silver Deputy badge for reaching a flag weight of 500
- added the gold Marshal badge for reaching a flag weight of 749

Comment: The [Marshal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/160/marshal) badge is for a flag rep of 749; 750 is theoretically ([but not practically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached/84569#84569)) asymptotic.

Comment: Ah, so the Marshall badge is why I recently see so many old "not an answer" flags popping up! :)