# Does [cheap] make sense as a tag on SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheap and the results didn't look much like programming questions. Is there anything that should be done about it? Anything *I* should do about it? If so, what?

Comment: That is indeed a meta tag. Once the [great turkey shoot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83214/the-great-moderator-flag-turkey-shoot) is over, I'll look into eliminating it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You called?

[image: burninated]
[image: no cheap stuff anymore]

---

Affected questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158792/java-web-hosting [close(1) off topic]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709674/looking-for-a-good-web-server-that-is-cheap [close(1) off topic]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223406/need-an-ev-ssl-certificate [webmasters]
- [cheap way to scale a rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438070/cheap-way-to-scale-a-rails-application) [I thought this was ok]
- [Load-testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358539/load-testing-tool) [2 not a real question]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100156/looking-for-simple-searchable-dms [close(3) superuser/serverfault]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297505/cheap-asp-net-hosting-mutiple-domains [close(3) webmasters/off]

Comment: While I appreciate the effort, I was hoping that people could use the link to the [cheap] tag search results to find the off-topic posts and close/delete them. *Then* you could remove the tag from the 2 or 3 remaining questions still using it.

Comment: @Gabe - I removed from 7 questions, and in that process, *also* closed as many as I saw fit (off topic/localized)

Comment: I saw that there were close votes on some, but didn't see that they were actually closed.

Comment: @Gabe This is a community site, all 10k users can see votes to close/delete. If not enough people feel strongly enough to close/delete, then the questions are fine to stay (less the cheap tag)

Comment: The whole point of my post here was to draw attention to those posts that were off topic. By removing the tag, the attention is no longer drawn to them, and the posts languish forever in obscurity.

Comment: @gabe you know that you can check my activity right? see answer

Comment: You have a lot of activity, you know!

Comment: @gabe Not enough that you cannot search between when you posted your question and when I posted my answer. But the 7 questions are now in the answer.