# Can I search for answers by the OP?

Tags: discussion, flags, search

I was out [turkey hunting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83214/the-great-moderator-flag-turkey-shoot) and noticed that lots of the answers I was flagging were written by the OP.

Is there a way to search for answers written by the same user as the question? Perhaps with <100 rep?

In case this isn't clear, I'm not looking for answers written by a specific person. I'm looking for a way to search for all answers where the author of the answer is the same as the author of the question that the answer is associated with.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @Richard: What do you mean? I haven't tried anything because I don't even know if it's possible.