# How do I find all current answers containing a string with UNDER a given number of votes?

Tags: feature-request, search

votes:0 find all answers with **more** than 0 votes, I wish to find answers with 0 or less votes.

I need the search to be done on the live data, as votes change often and "bad" answers geet deleted.

(I wish to use this for ["Easy ways to find answers that should be comments, for flagging purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/easy-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-comments-for-flagging-purposes/83105#83105)")

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [a data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1116/low-score-answers):

```sql
select top 10
    Id as [Post Link],
    Score
    from Posts
    where
        PostTypeId = 2 and
        Score <= 0
    order by Score asc
```

Comment: If I understand rightly, this will only search out of data answers, so no much good for looking for "none answers"

Comment: From my experience, the data there is very old..