# What should we do with comments posted as answers by low-rep users?

Tags: discussion, comments, not-an-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments incorrectly submitted as an answer instead: what should we do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/comments-incorrectly-submitted-as-an-answer-instead-what-should-we-do)
>   [What to do about low-rep users requesting more information in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27467/what-to-do-about-low-rep-users-requesting-more-information-in-answers)
>   [What to do with self-aware rule breaking posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85751/what-to-do-with-self-aware-rule-breaking-posts)

What should we do when users who haven't earned the privilege of leaving comments post comment-level content as answers? Should we flag as "not an answer" and let the mods clean things up?

**In particular, the cases that interest me are when the users *know* that they don't have the ability to leave a comment and say "I can't post a comment yet but..." in their "comment-answer".**

Should we up-vote to get the posters closer to being able to leave real comments?

My gut says to just flag as NAA, but I am curious about what others think.

---

Note to the delete voter(s): Since I did't find the other 3 questions linked as duplicates with what I searched on, leaving this undeleted may serve as a useful signpost for future users.

Comment: Title is confusin dude. Please reword it, Thank You Very Much

Comment: Sufficiently thorough comments should be auto-pushed to answers. I think

Comment: @Adel - I tried about 10 times before I posted to make it more clear. I'm open to suggestions on how it can be better.

Comment: A month ago I was left in the position of wanting to comment, but unable to do so. Perhaps the amount of rep needed to comment should be reduced?

Comment: Read it aloud -  "left as a comment because the user didn't have the rep to comment?"  just one *comment* yea?

Comment: Did you mean _"What should we do with comments that have been posted as an answer because the user didn't have the rep to comment"_?

Comment: Heh, thanks folks. Not enough coffee this morning. Title's fixed now.

Comment: @cdeszaq - Strange thing, I just understood it now but it turns out my original misunderstanding of your title was wrong. I need a coffee too. Thank You Very Much.

Comment: @ChrisF, it's properly a duplicate of the top-rated duplicate in your duplicate suggestion :-). A meta-duplicate if you will :-).

Comment: @Ben - well yes, you can select one of the other duplicate if you wish.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the best thing you can do is just flag them as "not an answer".

Why would somebody want to upvote them ? That makes no sense. I know it does get to the top of answers, but I do not think that affects something

Comment: Not saying _I_ would want to upvote, but I have seen others that have (and left a comment indicating as such)

Comment: You are... `Should we up-vote to get them closer?`

Comment: There's a difference between "should we do X?" and "I think we should do X," @cdeszaq. You two are using different definitions for the same words.

Comment: I normally flag as NAA in the expectation it will be converted, and if it would have made a sensible comment look and see if the poster has anything else worth upvoting to give them the ability to actually comment.

Comment: Upvoting a non-answer is pointless; the poster loses the rep when the non-answer is deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That was what I thought, which is partly why I included it in my question

Comment: +1. Such behavior should be discouraged. BTW, if somebody does this, they apparently do not know/care about concepts of SO*. ( = One more good reason not to let them comment anyway.)

Comment: Should newbies be allowed to comment with less effort? Just let admins or 5000+ users "unflag" their mute state. or something

Comment: @AloisMahdal The rationale for rep requirement on comments is to prevent spammers posting unnoticed spam. If someone makes a useful non spammy contribution but has to do it in the format of an answer as the system doesn't allow them any other way then I don't see it as something to get upset about or indicative that they "do not know/care about concepts of SO*."

Comment: @MartinSmith "*The rationale for rep requirement on comments is to prevent spammers posting unnoticed spam"* are you sure? Seems like a captcha--or registration requirement (wait, don't we already have it?) could do it.

Comment: @AloisMahdal - Comments don't bump questions but answers do. [At least I thought that was the justification maybe not then.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71390/145673)

Comment: @MartinSmith And yes. It is to be discouraged. The same way you would discourage *bugs as comments* in BTS or *commit messages* like "edited abc.conf". Not that you don't trust the user, but that the behavior undermines usability of the system, and you ***need*** everybody to understand how to use it correctly. (Silently advising them to stay passive until they can start being useful).