# Who raised the most helpful flags on Stack Overflow and Meta?

Tags: discussion, flags, statistics, helpful-flags

There is a lot of discussion around meta about how to raise a helpful flag and flags getting declined, but I wonder:

Who raised the largest number of helpful flags on Stack Overflow and Meta?

Comment: Related / duplicate (at least for the SO part): [Is there any place to see a leaderboard of top “Helpful Flaggers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308760/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel yes and also true about meta and one more thing should I add more popular site or it will be too broad.

Comment: The answer there gives a procedure for getting the leaderboard yourself. There are only [64 Marshals here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal), it shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: I've updated the top list for SO [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308765/295232).

Comment: I've read somewhere that one of the SO mods made a python script which found the obsolete comments by AI, and then flagged them. Probably he is the winner.

Comment: Can the close voters please state why they don't believe this question seeks input/discussion from the community (i.e. isn't a constructive question)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On here, the current leader would appear to be [PeterJ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/203972/peterj?tab=topactivity) with 3760 helpful flags. He even has more than the Smoke Detector spam bot. Peter is the only person with more than 3000 helpful flags so he's some way out in front.

To determine this, I simply went through the profiles of [everyone who has the marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal).

Stack Overflow has 2.9K marshals so it would be rather more tedious to go through all their profiles. There's at [least one person with tens of thousands of flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically) there because they've written a bot that comment flags on their behalf so they (or some other bot writer) are likely to be the winner there.

On Stack Overflow's Meta, there are 4 Marshals, so the winner is [honk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2675154/honk?tab=topactivity) with 859 helpful flags.

The number of helpful flags used to be something that was kept secret, that changed when profiles were rewritten and the information was accidentally leaked. When someone pointed that out, they decided that it simply wasn't something that needed to be secret, so we can now see it on everyone's profiles, but as far as I know it's only there, so you'd need to scrape all profiles with Marshal on a site for any other site. Fortunately, they are all smaller than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a list with all users with at least 500 helpful flags on Meta Stack Exchange as of 2024-03-13. To update this list, follow the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332733/295232), and please do not bump this post too often. Flags are important but not *that* important, and it's not a competition.

1. 6818 helpful flags: [greg-449](/users/233625/greg-449)
2. 6292 helpful flags: [Glorfindel](/users/295232/glorfindel)
3. 4161 helpful flags: [PeterJ](/users/203972/peterj)
4. 4067 helpful flags: [honk](/users/294055/honk)
5. 4041 helpful flags: [SmokeDetector](/users/266345/smokedetector) <sub><sup>(Note: [this is a bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically).)</sup></sub>
6. 3312 helpful flags: [rene](/users/158100/rene)
7. 3099 helpful flags: [Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog](/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog)
8. 2812 helpful flags: [gnat](/users/165773/gnat)
9. 2804 helpful flags: [Sebastian Simon](/users/289905/sebastian-simon)
10. 2408 helpful flags: [iBug says Reinstate Monica](/users/350567/ibug-says-reinstate-monica)
11. 2264 helpful flags: [Shadow Wizard Love Zelda](/users/152859/shadow-wizard-love-zelda)
12. 2146 helpful flags: [πάντα ῥεῖ](/users/186472/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96)
13. 1938 helpful flags: [bummi](/users/201151/bummi)
14. 1906 helpful flags: [John Dvorak](/users/194047/john-dvorak)
15. 1836 helpful flags: [4b0](/users/163529/4b0)
16. 1540 helpful flags: [Pang](/users/204869/pang)
17. 1522 helpful flags: [D.W.](/users/160917/d-w)
18. 1433 helpful flags: [Journeyman Geek](/users/135565/journeyman-geek)
19. 1432 helpful flags: [tripleee](/users/169312/tripleee)
20. 1407 helpful flags: [F1Krazy](/users/461068/f1krazy)
21. 1392 helpful flags: [Fish Below the Ice](/users/262755/fish-below-the-ice)
22. 1353 helpful flags: [starball](/users/997587/starball)
23. 1321 helpful flags: [Mithical](/users/294691/mithical)
24. 1276 helpful flags: [Makyen](/users/271271/makyen)
25. 1270 helpful flags: [Robert Longson](/users/188189/robert-longson)
26. 1268 helpful flags: [cigien](/users/800395/cigien)
27. 1266 helpful flags: [W.O.](/users/259608/w-o)
28. 1237 helpful flags: [Thomas F](/users/225607/thomas-f)
29. 1224 helpful flags: [Elements In Space](/users/938841/elements-in-space)
30. 1207 helpful flags: [PeterJames](/users/1242908/peterjames)
31. 1183 helpful flags: [Mysticial](/users/169611/mysticial)
32. 1165 helpful flags: [Anne Daunted GoFundMonica](/users/377968/anne-daunted-gofundmonica)
33. 1162 helpful flags: [Meta Andrew T.](/users/241919/meta-andrew-t)
34. 1139 helpful flags: [Robert Columbia](/users/336163/robert-columbia)
35. 1117 helpful flags: [V2Blast](/users/335251/v2blast)
36. 1116 helpful flags: [n8te](/users/370654/n8te)
37. 1099 helpful flags: [Nij](/users/341260/nij)
38. 1087 helpful flags: [This_is_NOT_a_forum](/users/63550/this-is-not-a-forum)
39. 1082 helpful flags: [Spevacus](/users/622284/spevacus)
40. 1033 helpful flags: [M.A.R.](/users/280934/m-a-r)
41. 1025 helpful flags: [Jamal](/users/217361/jamal)
42. 1022 helpful flags: [Arulkumar](/users/312043/arulkumar)
43. 1020 helpful flags: [CRABOLO](/users/244519/crabolo)
44. 1010 helpful flags: [PolyGeo](/users/215590/polygeo)
45. 986 helpful flags: [ale](/users/21960/ale)
46. 981 helpful flags: [hkotsubo](/users/401803/hkotsubo)
47. 977 helpful flags: [VLAZ](/users/394647/vlaz)
48. 958 helpful flags: [Luuklag](/users/361484/luuklag)
49. 957 helpful flags: [Mureinik](/users/223467/mureinik)
50. 956 helpful flags: [S.L. Barth is on codidact.com](/users/168333/s-l-barth-is-on-codidact-com)
51. 954 helpful flags: [Himanshu](/users/187824/himanshu)
52. 934 helpful flags: [Floern](/users/164356/floern)
53. 922 helpful flags: [JRN](/users/177408/jrn)
54. 898 helpful flags: [ProgramFOX](/users/229438/programfox)
55. 883 helpful flags: [Pika Supports Ukraine](/users/405220/pika-supports-ukraine)
56. 875 helpful flags: [francescalus](/users/253246/francescalus)
57. 864 helpful flags: [Chenmunka](/users/236563/chenmunka)
58. 858 helpful flags: [The Amplitwist](/users/986753/the-amplitwist)
59. 851 helpful flags: [hichris123](/users/237685/hichris123)
60. 851 helpful flags: [Bart](/users/161198/bart)
61. 842 helpful flags: [Martijn Pieters](/users/140890/martijn-pieters)
62. 832 helpful flags: [philipxy](/users/266284/philipxy)
63. 782 helpful flags: [srank](/users/341449/srank)
64. 778 helpful flags: [Unihedron](/users/266094/unihedron)
65. 763 helpful flags: [John Omielan](/users/562482/john-omielan)
66. 756 helpful flags: [apaderno](/users/140449/apaderno)
67. 747 helpful flags: [bad_coder](/users/665544/bad-coder)
68. 742 helpful flags: [Aziz Shaikh](/users/166025/aziz-shaikh)
69. 739 helpful flags: [Rand al'Thor](/users/278659/rand-althor)
70. 718 helpful flags: [toolic](/users/849201/toolic)
71. 715 helpful flags: [Lucifer](/users/173001/lucifer)
72. 710 helpful flags: [cocomac](/users/1081494/cocomac)
73. 706 helpful flags: [Laurel](/users/323179/laurel)
74. 699 helpful flags: [DavidPostill](/users/267099/davidpostill)
75. 699 helpful flags: [MattAllegro](/users/258978/mattallegro)
76. 694 helpful flags: [Catija](/users/284336/catija)
77. 694 helpful flags: [Mad Scientist](/users/151385/mad-scientist)
78. 693 helpful flags: [Patrick Hofman](/users/245360/patrick-hofman)
79. 685 helpful flags: [bobble](/users/1017231/bobble)
80. 666 helpful flags: [sempaiscuba](/users/437864/sempaiscuba)
81. 664 helpful flags: [Nog Shine](/users/357396/nog-shine)
82. 661 helpful flags: [Wrzlprmft](/users/255554/wrzlprmft)
83. 654 helpful flags: [caird coinheringaahing](/users/355458/caird-coinheringaahing)
84. 649 helpful flags: [Mast](/users/269301/mast)
85. 643 helpful flags: [Turamarth](/users/343987/turamarth)
86. 642 helpful flags: [Big Brother](/users/771581/big-brother)
87. 638 helpful flags: [Jenayah](/users/398063/jenayah)
88. 634 helpful flags: [Cody Gray - on strike](/users/153008/cody-gray-on-strike)
89. 625 helpful flags: [K.Dᴀᴠɪs](/users/380722/k-d%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%a0%c9%aas)
90. 622 helpful flags: [user642796](/users/214632/user642796)
91. 614 helpful flags: [نور](/users/738249/%d9%86%d9%88%d8%b1)
92. 613 helpful flags: [Suraj Rao](/users/347191/suraj-rao)
93. 604 helpful flags: [Christian Rau](/users/162011/christian-rau)
94. 602 helpful flags: [Flexo](/users/153020/flexo)
95. 599 helpful flags: [Tetsuya Yamamoto](/users/335888/tetsuya-yamamoto)
96. 588 helpful flags: [Nick Stauner](/users/246931/nick-stauner)
97. 582 helpful flags: [Undo](/users/215468/undo)
98. 572 helpful flags: [James Risner](/users/1244491/james-risner)
99. 550 helpful flags: [Rubiksmoose](/users/382836/rubiksmoose)
100. 546 helpful flags: [jonsca](/users/159165/jonsca)
101. 543 helpful flags: [Ral Zarek](/users/182868/ral-zarek)
102. 542 helpful flags: [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](/users/237989/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz)
103. 538 helpful flags: [Azik](/users/186599/azik)
104. 526 helpful flags: [a cat](/users/163265/a-cat)
105. 521 helpful flags: [Andy](/users/186281/andy)
106. 521 helpful flags: [Cai](/users/307988/cai)
107. 520 helpful flags: [Nobody](/users/217406/nobody)
108. 517 helpful flags: [JonathanDavidArndt](/users/365152/jonathandavidarndt)
109. 507 helpful flags: [Antony](/users/209357/antony)

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Note that once the post is updated using the script in the linked post, your note will get removed, since the script doesn't output it. If you want to ensure it stays, please edit the linked script so it recognizes the name and outputs it.