# Is there a way to find users with the largest number of helpful flags?

Tags: feature-request, support, flags, users, statistics

In each user's profile, number of helpful flags is displayed - so this is a public information. However, I did not find this number in the [data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

**Question:** Is there some simple way to find the users who have the biggest number of helpful flags? Possibly also ordered by number of flags and showing the number of flags somewhere?

I know that I could look at the [Marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal) to see all users who have at least 500 helpful flags. However, if I wanted to find out who is the "leader" in this statistic, I would have to check each user profile individually.

This question is to some extent motivated by curiosity. Still, the numbers of flags by individual users give some insight into which users help with curating and moderating the site. (Similarly as number of reviews and some other tasks - <s>which can be obtained from [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), as far as I can tell.</s>)

**Proposal:** If currently there is no way to do this (using website interface or SEDE), let me also add a feature request to include this possibility somewhere.

EDIT: Glorfindel directed me in comments to another question where he provides a script getting the list of top flaggers. So I suppose that only the feature request part of this question now remains.

Comment: See [Is there any place to see a leaderboard of top “Helpful Flaggers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308760/295232) - I wrote a script there which you can use to generate a list. I don't think they'll ever develop a proper leaderboard; flagging is important but not a game. Another related question is [Who raised most number of helpful flags on Stack Overflow and Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332672/295232).

Comment: FWIW, you can't get review leaderboards from SEDE; the reviewer information has been stripped.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the response. I do not know whether I made some mistake when running the script - however, it seems that I only got users from the first page in the list of users with Marshal badge. (Maybe I made some mistake when running the script? I have posted more details [in Addons & Scripts chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/90615/2020/5/3).)