# Why doesn't close vote count toward Deputy/Marshal

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm just curious why close votes dont seem to count as helpful for deputy/marshal badges. It seems like they should since when you get to 3k you get your ability to flag questions replaced by vote close.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Good point. Before I reached 3k on MSO, I used to get tons of flags a day. Now I get very few.

Comment: Remember, it's not _replaced_, more of _shunted_ -- you still can flag.

Comment: i think you can only get them with the evil low quality tag after 3k

Comment: @Manishearth it seems like the only one that actually flags is low quality all others seem to be converted to close votes without incrementing your helpful flags

Comment: Really? Didn't know that o_0

Comment: No. The only ones that are converted to close votes after 3k are the "it does not belong here" options. You can tell that the pop-up visually changes to a different one after you click it. The "very low quality", "other", "spam", and "it is not welcome in our community" options all raise a flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voting to close is not the same as flagging. Once you've reached 3k rep, the system trusts you enough to know when to cast a vote to close.

Flagging should be reserved for serious incidents.

If you're aiming for the badges - you can still achieve them by going through [review](/review) route & use Not an Answer / Custom mod flags judiciously.

Comment: I suppose the point isnt to try for the flags they are really a reward for good behavior. But i suppose it seems wierd that low quality flagging is encouraged by this logic.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I wouldn't say it's encouraged - flags can be declined and results in you getting lesser number of flags

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - I only use Very Low Quality to flag things I think should be deleted and aren't worth editing to fix any obvious problems because there's still a fundamental problem even after the best possible edit that could be made.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - The original purpose of this badge was to make people aware of the fact that they could cast flags for items that can't easily be handled through normal means. For example, we're flooded with non-answers every day (people asking questions in answers, chiming in with "me too", or spamming irrelevant links). You can quickly get these badges from running several of these queries over a few days: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited . I say this as someone who's cast 7900 flags, with only 12 declined.

Comment: However, gaining the badges via this route is vastly more difficult than when sub 3k...

Answer (score 3):

Simply, a vote to close is not a flag.

You're not flagging any more so you can't increment your helpful flag count by this method. If you are still trying to flag that something should be closed once you have passed 3K reputation then **you're doing it wrong**. This is why flags to close are converted to votes to close.

You can still flag for other reasons - Spam, Very Low Quality etc.

Also if you run out of close votes for the day you can revert to flagging.

Comment: I agree trying to flag when you can vote close is wrong. I suppose my point was that these badges arent really achievable to people with higher reputation which seems wierd. Prehaps there should be a counterpart for closing questions

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - yes they are. My helpful flags are still inching upwards on SO and SU despite having full privileges. Use the `review` page to find low quality stuff to edit and flag. Spam always turns up and needs flagging.

Comment: there seems to be a lot of discussion on low quality flagging, it seems like we should be using other flags/votes instead. However low quality flag is mildly encouraged by making it the only path to helpful flags

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - the primary route for low quality stuff should be editing and down-votes. It's the answers that should be comments etc that need flagging.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - there's plenty of other things that are worth flagging. I suspect the most helpful flags are the one where you have spotted a more complex situation and have to describe it in the "other" box instead of using a canned flag.

Comment: @awoodland yeah i kinda agree with that

Comment: "if you run out of close votes for the day you can revert to flagging." - Actually you can't.

Comment: @haydoni - you can always use the "other" option.

Comment: @ChrisF Good point, I'll try that and see if it works!

Comment: @ChrisF you *can* but it's seemingly ineffective (perhaps there is a large backlog?).