# Should "Best short examples of the need for Excel VBA" be flagged?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

I have taken a hand at editing to improve my knowledge of a language and to improve its question set - VBA and its variants. While I have read the article on finding [flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited) and the FAQ several times, I am uncertain how to always categorize questions that seem helpful but which lack scope.

For instance, should [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704572/best-short-examples-of-the-need-for-excel-vba) be flagged for closure, given that it is generalized to the language alone and does not address a specific issue of that language? Or is it just a very useful but kind of general question that serves the users well, i.e. left quietly alone?

Comment: That was also an old question, many of which are still out there, whose presence doesn't really fit with the way the site currently works. I suspect that the same question posted today would be quickly closed and not left hanging like your example. If it does not meet the guidelines set forth the in FAQ (relate to a specific programming problem), then flag it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Job done by the community. I (and four others) couldn't see a way to edit it into a form that would be appropriate for keeping open, which would be preferred, so we voted to close it. Improving the question can sometimes be done if the answers are consistent enough.