# How to list old posts?

Tags: support

I just saw that there's a badge for editing old posts. So, I'd like to know how I can list old posts (let's say within C#).

Also, is it possible to check how many oldies I've already been into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the age of the site, chances are that any post you open other than by using the Questions tab or clicking on one of your favourite tags (those are sorted newest first) will be an old one. If you use some clever searches (there are tons in [What are the best ways to find answers that should be flagged or edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited/) ) and come across crap, then edit it, I bet you'll be editing old posts a lot of the time. If you're able to flag, you'll also be flagging questions as off topic or answers as not an answer some of the time - not everything can be fixed by editing.

Before you know it you'll have cleaned up the site and earned some shiny badges at the same time.

Comment: This is really weird (and totally off-topic). In my mailbox I got a header of your reply but with a typo - *of the* **ago** *of the site*. Still, I can't see that you edited your post. Do we have ghosts on Meta?

Comment: Also, I just got Archaeologist badge. Apparently I've been unknowingly doing the right thing already. :)

Comment: There's a 5 minnute grace period in which you can make "ninja edits". I got a comment about the typo and fixed it, then the commenter deleted the comment. Almost no trace!

Comment: Naa, I prefer my explanation. Let's agree it was a ghost that pointed out your typo. :)