# Cleanup based on a search

Tags: discussion

Since tag cleanups are suggested pretty often, I would like to ask if cleanups by search would be appropriate to.
The search I am thinking about would be [how to start learning](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=how%20to%20start%20learning), which I primarily used to confirm a close reasons on a question found in the 10+k tools. The questions found there have a high percentage of "asking for resource" , "to broad" or "primarily opinion based".

Comment: That is totally a fine way to find crap questions. Also to make it easy to get rid of the worst questions I would suggest starting out here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=27&tab=votes&q=how%20to%20start%20learning%20closed%3a1

Comment: I do this regularly to [find non-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited). I see no problems in doing so, as long as it's within reason (don't overload the front page with edits, etc.), and you are indeed reading each post and not blindly flagging or voting based only on a search term (we do, unfortunately, see this sometimes).

Comment: @BradLarson, thanks for answering. I would like to believe I'm not blind flagging, voting or closing, but I may have a fundamentally wrong evaluation. Comparing the success of a close vote with the success of a vote from the review, I'm not sure if I'm on the wrong path with my judgment on questions or if this is caused be the (suspected) prioritization of questions in the review.