# Flagging and Voting to Close

Tags: discussion, flags, badges

I was reading the other questions about how flags now convert to close votes since I just breached 3k rep, and I was wondering -- does this mean I am no longer eligible to obtain the Marshall Badge (500 flags)? I'm at 142 right now and I'm kind of bummed out to hear that I might not be able to get the badge anymore.

Comment: Don't forget flagging comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will still be able to get it, by flagging answers.

"Closing" applies to questions; answers aren't "closed" or "put on hold". Answers can be deleted, but this is different from closing/putting on hold.

When a question is closed/put on hold, one can no longer answer it. Since answers are not answered in turn, "closing" an an answer or "putting an answer on hold" would not make sense.

Comment: How? Flags are converted to close votes and I read it would be abuse to flag questions

Comment: "Flagging would be considered abuse of the system so, as you have noticed, if you attempt to flag it is automatically converted to a vote. So you can no longer flag for this reason." - ChrisF (moderator)

Comment: Ahhh I get it!!

Comment: @AlienArrays Off the top of my head, I don't think you can flag-to-close after using up your close votes.

Comment: @AlienArrays No, please do not use the non closure flags in place of close votes. That's not what they're for, and they will likely get declined or disputed. Just bookmark the question and come back the next day to cast your close vote.

Answer (score 8):

Only flags to close get converted into close votes. Spam, Offensive, Very Low Quality, and Other flags do not. And neither do any flags on answers.

Between all these different flag types, Marshall is certainly not out of reach.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: @RUJordan - I should point out that I only started to flag things well after I was at the 3k marker. If you look all of us who were the first to earn this badge, almost everyone started at that point as well. Most of the things that need to be flagged on the site don't have to do with question closure, and I used to burn through all of my daily flags with stuff like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited .