# Can we have an approve and improve button or reason field?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

(I'm not active on SO but I am active on Ask Ubuntu and this seems like a network question so I hope this is ontopic, even though I feel like SO has probably solved this sort of thing in some other way)

Right now I get accept, reject, or improve on a pending edit. I've seen:

- [Do we need a 'reject and improve' button?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button)

But I'd like to ask for an improve and accept option. I appreciate that the original submitter still gets his/her +2, but considering these are newish users who might be new and have already taken the step towards improving the site I'd like to have the ability to leave them a reason for the edit as a word of encouragement.

As an example:

Now:

- (new person) "wow this answer sucks, I'd like to improve it" *submit edit*
- (me) hmm, mostly right, let me fix it up for the win, I'll hit improve and just fix it.
- (new person) wait what? I submitted stuff that was right and this crazy guy added all this stuff and I don't know why?

Better:

- (new person) "wow this answer sucks, I'd like to improve it" *submit edit*
- (me) mostly right, let me fix it up for the win. "hey bro I like what you did here; foo, bar is great, baz is kind of crap so I'm not accepting that, welcome to ask ubuntu, here's the faq, keep at it!"
- (new person) omg I feel so enabled.

Comment: minor concern is that if we add to many hurdles to "improve" and "reject" people will avoid those buttons in favor of "approve"

Answer (score 1):

This is something I'd like to see also.

I also see a lot of edits suggested that start to do a good job, but leave a lot of bad grammar, or misspelled words, or have salutations, valedictions or signatures hanging around. I'd like to be able to suggest an improved edit for that person to use if I reject it.

In addition, I regularly see edits suggested by newbies who are changing an answer someone else submitted, rather than use the comment to suggest a change. I'd like to be able to reject those edits with a "Please do not change other people's submitted answers, instead add a comment", or something similar.

Finally, I'd like to be able to click a checkbox for the accept button that will give the user an "atta-boy" or a gold star for that edit, to add a bit of extra encouragement for a great edit suggestion. I've seen some people crank out edits that are consistently doing a very good job, which benefits the site. Heck, it'd be nice if the checkbox gave them an added +1 rep boost too.

Comment: Approved edits heap +2 on the contributor

Comment: Yes but a gold star should add a gold +2, redeemable as an extra 1 point. :-)