# Is a suggested edit accepted or rejected when someone selects "Improve"?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I've been editing a question and I realized there is already a suggested edit pending. If I select "Improve" instead of "Accept", what is the impact of this in the total of accepted and rejected edits suggestions to the user?

Comment: It's accepted, and the proposing editor gets their +2 reputation points. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button) for more details. I'm inclined to agree that we need a "reject and improve" button. @random is right that more people need to hit "Reject", but until they start doing that, too many bad edits are approved. I reject lots of edits that two other people go on to approve, and I have to remember to go back and make the rest of the edits I think need to be made.

Comment: @CodyGray You should post that as an answer. The body of that question has the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 6):

It counts as being accepted by the [Community♦ user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Answer (score 4):

The suggested edit is accepted by the [Community ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user, and the proposing editor gets their full +2 reputation points.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button) for more details. I'm inclined to agree that we need a "Reject and Improve" button. @random is right that more people need to man up and hit "Reject", but until they start doing that, I see far too many bad edits being approved. I reject lots of edits that two other people go on to approve, and with the current system, I'm forced into remembering to go back and make the rest of the edits I think need to be made.

Comment: Is it possible for women to "man up"?