# When I choose to "Improve" a suggested edit, make me the approver, not Community

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improved edit suggestions approved by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community)

As explained clearly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90903/is-a-suggested-edit-accepted-or-rejected-when-someone-selects-improve), when I choose to "Improve" a suggested edit, the Community user is shown as the approver.

I think it would make more sense if I appeared as the approver though, e.g. in this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/74973), it would look more correct if it was shown as:

> Approved 5 mins ago by Shamim Hafiz, Shadow Wizard

Because currently "Improve" means "Approve and edit".

Unless someone can explain the logic behind this decision?