# Often I am seeing suggested edits that should be comments

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Often I am seeing suggested edits that should be comments.
E.g.

> Edited does not work in when i pass button in withObject..

Added  at the end of a post

Can we have some easy way to convert a suggested edit into a comment and/or a suggested comment system.

Comment: If the suggested edit is by the OP & is clarification on the question, it should be approved as an edit. Otherwise it should be flat out rejected.

Comment: [People need to harden up and hit that Reject button more.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button/83725#83725)

Comment: Sometimes, it would be a useful commnet like "xxx did not work for me" so that other people did not spend a long time trying to do what the answer says.

Comment: Ditto this: these comments are sometimes worth saving. For the really good ones I've started adding a comment myself, linking to the user and suggested edit and quoting the change, but the workflow could be easier. If the user makes a single contiguous addition to the text it'd be useful to have the option of converting it to a comment attributed to that user. (but I realise this is possibly a corner case and there's bigger problems to deal with, e.g. all these "improve formatting" editors who bold random words and code-tag others.)