# Can trivial edits not bump the question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers)
>   [Feature request: Trivial-edit checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/feature-request-trivial-edit-checkbox)

Can we add the option *not* to bump a message when editing?  The idea goal would be not to bump small grammatical, punctuation, capitalization, spelling, and formatting changes, that improve the post, but don't substantially change it.

The reasoning for this is that on many of the smaller sites, it becomes annoying when posts are bumped to the front page for corrections that, IMO, greatly improve the quality of the site/community, but don't really change the core of the post in ways that will interest people who may already have seen the post.

I can see two possible methods of implementing this.  It might be best to choose just one, or maybe a combination of the two.

1. Automatically detect "trivial" edits, and don't bump posts that only meet the following criteria:

   - Capitalization changes
   - punctuation-only or whitespace-only changes
   - Fewer than N characters were changed (perhaps 6, since we already use that number as a limit for low-rep edits for similar reasons?)
   - Juxtaposition of letters (change 'ect' into 'etc')
2. Add a **Don't bump this post** check-box next near the "Save Edits" button, that could be checked if the editor feels his edits are trivial enough not to warrant a "bump".

   This might be abused by people trying to "sneak their edits in," so it should probably only be available to users of sufficiently high reputation, and/or require review, even when the editor does have high reputation.

Comment: Although I agree with the proposal.

Comment: #1 is problematic because it would be endorsing trivial edits; we *tolerate* them, but otherwise we want substantive edits. #2 is like the "I'm not evil" checkbox. Just check it if you're not evil. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Perhaps "trivial" is not a good word choice. Perhaps "small but substantive" is better. The point is, many "small but substantive" edits are worth while from a quality standpoint, but don't change the post sufficiently to warrant a re-read by the community. This is especially true for old posts found via Google. I like to clean up quality errors in such a post, but this doesn't make the post suddenly worthy of front-page attention. Regarding the "I'm not evil" bit... that's what an approval process would be for.

Comment: A proposal similar to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/front-page-flood-rate-control-system-for-editing) for "small" edits would also address my concern over the tension between "Improve the site" and "Don't monopolize the front page with your edits"

Comment: No -- simply click the giant Questions link on the homepage if you want to filter out edits. Beyond that, make substantive edits or just don't bother, honestly.