# Feature: "Do not tweet" checkbox for edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, twitter

When we edit questions, there is an algorithm that runs in the background to figure out what is interesting and tweet it.

I'm serving as a commuity mod on ne.se... I just [edited a question's tags](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/2219/revisions) that were wrong and the question got retweeted...  That question was inactive for almost a month...

My feature request has a similar motivation as the [Trivial Edit Checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102499/feature-request-trivial-edit-checkbox) question, although I hope my request has a better fate.

**Feature request:**

Please include a checkbox called "Do not tweet" in edit view; if asserted, 
this checkbox should override any algorithmic decision to tweet the question 
immediately after the edit which had the box checked.

In other words, give us control so we don't accidentally tweet cleanup activity.

Comment: Wouldn't the more general 'do not bump posts' trivial edit feature request be a better option? It would include not tweeting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I fully support the trivial edit checkbox linked in my question, but that is status-declined

Comment: Well, you may have another good reason to have that decision reversed. If *this* gets approved and implemented, next thing we'll have another 3 feature requests to also switch off other processes normally trigged by an edit, and we'd have that feature request but in a fragmented set of disparate checkboxes instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the problem with the general "do not bump" requests are vandalizing edits. And yes, even high-rep users do that occasionally. This is not really an issue when only tweets are disableable.