# Hunk level control when approving edits/reverting changes

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rollbacks

Some edits or suggested edits contain a mixture of good and bad;  Particularly, *body* edits are usually for the better, but In the name of phrasing titles as questions, the title loses the specifics, or noise tags are added for no obvious reason.

In my ideal world, I'd be able to select *some* of the edited sections for approval, and then follow up with a second edit to improve the remaining issues that the original editor fell short on.

That would mean that the original suggestions are credited to the original suggester, and many people can quickly contribute to making the post better.

Comment: Isn't that what the "Improve" button is for? Keep the stuff you like, junk the stuff you don't. The original suggester *does* get his/her 2 rep points this way.

Comment: @dlev Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Chris Done and done.

Answer (score 5):

This particular functionality seems to be covered by the current "Improve" button. It allows you to make whatever further changes you like, including rolling back parts of the edit you didn't like, as well as adding your own touches. Once you submit, both your edit and the original suggeter's edit are committed *at the same time*. As well, the original editor *does* get their 2 rep points.

Comment: The problem is when we don't feel like giving the guy +2 for capitalizing the first word in the title while leaving 10 misspelled words in the body.

Comment: @Bo Fair enough. So something like a "Reject and Improve" button? Even if the edit is minor (and could have done more) it doesn't bother me too much to award 2 rep points.

Comment: It does bother me when the same guy does it 10 times in a row. :-)

Comment: @Bo I could see that :) I guess for now there will always be "Reject" and "Edit" instead of "Reject and Edit".

Comment: The problem with "Reject" followed by "Edit" is that you also have to wait for someone else to vote on it. Of course, this has been hashed out before. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button