# Completely anonymise ALL review tasks and audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-audits

I feel it would be beneficial in the long term if we *completely anonymised* **all** review tasks, either by completely removing all user cards, or by simply replacing them with a placeholder "A #StackSite# User" card. Allow me to explain how and why I think this would be of benefit. I will summarise each point here and then expand upon them afterwards (this list also serves as a **TL;DR** section). I may add more things to this as I think of them.

- **It would make real tasks and audits consistent**
- **Avoids bias: *Who* performed the action under review is not relevant**

---

### It would make real tasks and audits consistent

Currently audits are anonymised so that you don't know which users are involved. This is as it should be - *who* isn't important, it's the content that we're reviewing. The author should have no bearing on that whatsoever. What we don't currently do is anonymise *real tasks* (this is certainly true of the First Posts and Late Answers queues - I am assuming that it is true of the others as well). This seems counterproductive.

Anyone that's paying even a little attention should be able to work out if they're looking at an audit because if it is, the users will have been anonymised, whereas they won't have been for real tasks. If it's easy for us as reviewers to spot when we're being audited *then the audit system doesn't work properly*. **We *should not* be able to tell that we're being audited until *after* the event.**

### Avoids bias: *Who* performed the action under review is not relevant

The subject of any review task is either a *question or an answer*, *never* a user. I have *no reason to know* who posted the content because their identity *is not relevant to the review task*. In the majority of cases that I have come across this isn't an issue because I'm not familiar with the user posting the content, I can be impartial in those cases because I have no bias. The problem with displaying the user's identity is that it *can* introduce bias to the review.

Whether I like it or not and no matter how hard I try, I'm more likely to favourably review something from people like Jon Skeet or BalusC than I am something from user23875476687. I'm only human, and being completely impartial is difficult, especially when I know the content I'm reviewing is from a highly respected, high quality contributor. It's *possible* that this bias can lead to someone reviewing content differently based solely upon the author *instead of the content*.

---

Personally I favour removing the user card completely. There isn't any information on the card that is pertinent to a review task (the date/time that it was posted is irrelevant, as is the user's reputation, username, gravatar and badge totals), so I don't see any reason to display one at all.

Of course, a side effect of this may be that it makes audits more difficult to pass, but I don't necessarily see that as a bad thing. But please note, this isn't the place to discuss disputed review audits - that's a separate issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I often spot the audits based on the content alone, so further anonymising the review wouldn't make it any harder or easier to spot the audits. Besides that, the audits are meant to catch out the users that don't pay attention, so being able to spot them if you pay attention isn't a problem.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau But what is it that we want reviewers to pay attention to? Do we want them to pay attention simply to if it's an audit or not, or do we want them to pay more attention to the content that they're reviewing? Surely the latter? Also, inexperienced lower-reputation reviewers vastly outnumber experienced high-reputation users. I would imagine that audits stick out like a sore thumb when you're an experienced reviewer and that's largely fine (but is there an argument there for making harder audits for experienced reviewers?)

Comment: I asked a similar question with reduced scope a while back: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107232/anonymous-editors-in-edit-queue-would-produce-more-objective-decisions

Comment: @Flexo Seems I've unwittingly brought up a controversial topic!

Answer (score 5):

The user that authored the post *is* relevant when reviewing though.  For example, a post that seems like potential spam/advertising may involve looking at the user's history to confirm whether or not it's spam (it can also help determine whether or not there is an issue of a failure to divulge an association with a product).

And of course the information is still there on the link to the post itself.  It's just making the information an extra click away, it's not hiding it entirely.  Someone truly interested in accessing the information still has access to it either way.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that we remove the link to the full question/answer (I'm undecided about it, but I use it fairly regularly myself), so you would still be able to carry out that investigation if you suspect that's what's going on.

Comment: @JonK Then, as per my second point, removing it is pointless.  Anyone who wants to abuse the information still can.  At some point you have to ask yourself what's more important, preventing people from finding out that an audit is an audit without actually evaluating the content, or providing tools to let good reviewers do their job.  Me, I'm in the latter camp.  A change to try to make audits harder to cheat that also makes real reviews harder to review is causing net harm.  If the good reviewers can't review properly there's no point in having the queue to begin with.

Comment: *Good* reviewers tend not to fail review audits anyway (and if they do, it often ends up being posted as a disputed audit anyway). There is **no point** in having review audits if you can easily see that it's an audit before you complete it. To me that suggests we need to do one of two things: Either remove the audits completely, or make them harder to detect. I'd rather make them harder to detect because they *do* serve a purpose, however imperfectly.

Comment: @JonK You seem to be under the impression that nobody ever fails audits, ever.  That's simply not true.  SE has posted stats about it from time to time to indicate clearly that the audits are highly effective at keeping many of the worst users out of the system.  While abuse is certainly possible, many people simply don't have sufficient motivation to try to learn how to bypass the abuse prevention mechanisms.  While it certainly doesn't do everything that I'd like it to do, it does clearly help to some degree.

Comment: @JonK And of course your proposed change isn't the only way of identifying audits.  So this change would inhibit proper reviewers, but still leave mechanisms for truly motivated malicious users to identify audits.  That's pretty much always going to be the case.  It's practically impossible to completely remove any means of determining whether or not a post is an audit without evaluating it's content, and trying to do so would almost certainly be a big problem for the good reviewers.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from `tend not to fail` to `never fail`. I *know* good reviewers fail audits - there's ample evidence of that on Meta.SO. I suppose my suggestion is to specifically target those users (and I include myself in this group) who *could eventually be* good reviewers **but aren't there yet**. I pay attention to reviews, but I don't remember the last audit I had where I hadn't noticed that it was an audit before I chose an action. That's not helpful for me in any way.

Comment: I doubt there's anything we could realistically do to prevent "truly motivated malicious users" from identifying audits. They can always just search for the question title if it comes down to it; but making it harder at least slows them down.

Comment: @JonK Audits are there to make sure that people are paying attention and not just blindly clicking a button.  That's all.  They're there to get rid of a specific type of actively malicious users.  They're not there to turn well intentioned and enthusiastic but inexperienced/ineffective reviewers into knowledgable reviewers.  It's simply not a design goal of the feature.  Your problems seem to stem from expecting reviews to be something that they just aren't.

Comment: @JonK But that's just it, the stats would seem to indicate that the audits are already enough of a deterrent to slow down a fair number of people, and most of those that it doesn't, wouldn't be stopped by this change either.

Comment: There's no reason that review audits can't also be used as a tool to help educate the inexperienced, well intentioned and enthusiastic at the same time though. I would hope there's more reason to the current audits than you're suggesting there is though, and that if there isn't there probably should be.

Comment: @JonK There are plenty of reasons that inhibit their use as such a tool, and the existence of a user card isn't even on that list.  It is extremely difficult to find a scaleable way of choosing situations that appropriate represent teachable moments (correctly).  Doing that is *very* hard.  Much, much harder than just having situations that are so completely obvious that anyone paying even the slightest bit of attention would recognize correctly.  The problem with that proposal has virtually nothing to do with whether or not a user card is shown.