# Improving a suggested edit for a tag excerpt shows the "community wiki" checkbox

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I was improving a [suggested edit for a tag excerpt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/21296/revisions), and I noticed the "community wiki" checkbox. I didn't select it because the excerpt should already be a community wiki, but then I had the doubt I should have selected it.

[image: screenshot]

Does that checkbox appear because what it is shown is the usual post edit form, or does that checkbox have a different meaning in this case?

If I try to edit an existing tag wiki, or its excerpt, I don't see the checkbox.

Comment: *edges towards it is shown is the usual post edit form.... then [blames waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button/109769#109769)*