# Editing tag wiki excepts from the review queue ignores character limit

Tags: bug, review, tag-wiki-excerpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improving a suggested edit on a tag wiki excerpt lets me exceed the excerpt max length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132383/improving-a-suggested-edit-on-a-tag-wiki-excerpt-lets-me-exceed-the-excerpt-max)

In the process of editing a tag wiki excerpt from the review queue, I exceeded the character limit by 112 characters:
https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/509

After I submitted the edit (directly from the review queue), the tag wiki excerpt was updated ([see the tag here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kings-indian)), however the tag wiki excerpt is cut off.

Additionally, when editing the tag wiki, the current length is not allowed via the regular tag wiki editing page:

[image: tag wiki excerpt is too long]

To summarize, edit a tag wiki excerpt from within the review queue and the character limit is not enforced.

Comment: upon further meta searching, probably a duplicate of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132383/172726