# What's the purpose of the "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just [approved an anonymous edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8358) by clicking the `improve` button.

I did some minor touchups on the answer and removed excess on the suggested edit. At the bottom, I found a checkbox I haven't seen before:

[image]

**What's the purpose of this box?** Why would I need to check that the edit was helpful? It obviously was, since I've already accepted it (or, improved, for that matter).

So, what gives?

Comment: _"It obviously was [helpful], since I've already accepted it"_ Not necessarily; see [Do we need a 'Reject and Improve' button?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button)

Comment: Well, then I would reject, and then edit myself. (But I'd love to have this button regardless)

Comment: You would have to wait for another reviewer to _also_ reject before editing yourself. Edits are disallowed until suggestions are resolved. That's the reason behind the feature request.

Comment: SO is different here because it actually needs two reviewers. We don't have this problem on SU, but I get it now :)

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that. I get your confusion now. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this checkbox was removed and the "Improve" option was split into "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's [the implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109769/150235) of a request for "reject & improve" functionality.

There are circumstances where a post needed to be edited, but the edit suggested was poor to the point of being unhelpful. If a reviewer is inclined to continue through with improving the post, they now have an option of indicating to the editor that their suggestion was poor (by having Community reject the suggested edit with no reputation increase to the editor) and providing an example of what a good edit might look like by submitting their own improvements immediately.