# Should we able to keep edits when rejecting and editing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

**Context:**

Today I encountered an issue when reviewing an edit. The edit itself was on a poorly formatted question, and it fixed the formatting, *but added another question from the editor*. My semi-viable options were to:

- Improve the edit, then remove the new question raised by the editor. This (in my opinion) wouldn't be the best course of action due to the +2 reputation gain which may encourage bad edits
- Reject and improve, which may be alright, but the code was incredibly long. Choosing to reject and edit would reset **all** previous changes by the edit suggester. I found it very inconvenient to have to reindent and format
- Reject altogether then going back to edit the indentation, thus leading to the same problem mentioned above and would need 2 others to do the same

None of these options seemed perfect. I leaned towards rejecting and editing as it wouldn't give +2, but as mentioned above I would have to reindent everything. I finally opted to improve the edit, removing the extra question, but I felt the +2 shouldn't have been given.

**Proposal:**

Before I start, I was wondering what happened to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109769/332767) "feature". This would probably solve the problem.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I see an okay suggested edit, but there's one part that invalidates the suggestion, I would have to reject and redo the good part of the edit if I were to reject and edit. Others would probably recommend to just improve the edit, but what if that one bad part of the edit doesn't warrant the +2 given when improving an edit?

My proposal is to have a button, when rejecting an editing, that restores the suggested edit:

[image]

So, in the above situation, instead of having to reindent and reformat (the good part of the edit) when rejecting and editing, I could just restore the suggesting and edit out the additional question (the bad part of the edit). This would *not* reward the user with +2 and would ultimately be the better choice in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle partially correct edits in the Suggested Edits review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310824/how-do-i-handle-partially-correct-edits-in-the-suggested-edits-review-queue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something of a workaround:

1. Click *Improve Edit* to get the edit box.
2. Select and copy all the text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
3. Click the "cancel" link to get back to the main review task view.
4. Click *Reject and Edit* to get an edit box for rejection.
5. Replace the text with the suggestion on your clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
6. Edit as necessary and submit.

The suggestion is considered rejected, but you didn't have to redo all the good parts in the body. You do have to manually handle the title and tags, though.

Comment: This is a working workaround, and might be the only way. I was looking for more of a native implementation but if this is the only way to achieve such a thing, I'll have to go with it.