# Give back the ability to indicate that a suggested edit is not helpful when improving

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Prior to 2014, the ways by which a reviewer of a suggested edit could apply another edit when reviewing were different. The "Reject and Edit" option didn't exist, and the only option was to "Improve". This would allow the reviewer to apply more edits on top of the suggestion, as the "Improve Edit" option does today.

Unlike the current "Improve Edit" option, though, once the reviewer made changes, they were shown a checkbox as to whether or not the suggested edit was helpful. Keeping the box checked retains the same behavior as today's button: it credits the user with an edit approval and 2 reputation. Unchecking the box, however, would make the Community user reject the edit and the user would not receive credit for the edit.

When the 2014 changes took place, as a replacement for the checkbox, a "Reject and Edit" button was added to handle edits that are bad but the post has other unrelated things that need to be edited; unlike the Improve Edit button, this button would start the editor with the current (not suggested) revision.

On many sites, posts get edit suggestions that are useful in that they fix issues with specific parts of the post, but fail to address other issues with the post that are blatant. As an example, a low-quality Stack Overflow post that uses bad grammar and capitalization in its prose and improperly formatted code may get a suggested edit that properly formats the code and applies the correct syntax highlighting, but doesn't address the problems with the prose.

The typical policy for such edits today is to click Improve Edit and fix the prose issues. However, as this has the effect of approving the suggested edit, this signals to the user who suggested that the edit was correct and that they should continue to suggest such edits. However, Stack Overflow (and I think it's a network-wide policy) discourages such edits and prefers suggested edits that address *all or most* issues with the post. If a reviewer doesn't want to take the time to fix the missed issues, they should review as Reject and use the "no improvement" reason or type out a custom reason explaining the missed parts. It's useful today to have a button that takes the edit suggestion (which did a good job at fixing the parts it did) and allows the reviewer to make more edits on top of it and at the same time mark the edit as rejected.

This functionality does technically exist today, and there are two ways to use it today:

- Initially click "Improve Edit", copy the post body to the clipboard, go back and choose "Reject and Edit", and select all and paste the suggested body.

  This is quite tedious, and I don't imagine many reviewers will do this every time such an edit comes up in the queue, and it's even more tedious if the post is a question and the suggestion edits the title and/or tags: those have to be copied in as well.

  Additionally, one may initially notice just a few additional changes that need to be made and click Improve Edit, but as they later proceed to do those changes, find that the edit fails to address most of the problems with the post and should not be marked as approved; it's much easier to just uncheck a box than do the tedious things above once the reviewer finds this.
- Use the fact that the old checkbox still exists in the page DOM and is merely hidden. This involves going into Developer Tools in one's Web browser and editing the page CSS to remove the attribute that hides the checkbox, or writing a user script that does so automatically.

  The user script solution resolves the tediousness of the first solution, but is not ideal since the way the old method was implemented was by [intentionally triggering an edit conflict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350026/377214) so the Community user would make a binding Reject review. Suggested edits auto-rejected as edit conflicts don't count toward automatic suspensions or flags for the suggesting user, and the system has since been changed to annotate such rejections explicitly as edit conflicts (previously, they didn't have any rejection message), making this solution non-ideal.

Someone in the comments also brought up the point that these workarounds, along with the pre-2014 functionality itself, would not attribute the editor in the revision history, a potential violation of the CC BY-SA license.

This review ambiguity is (I'm guessing) one small factor as to why suggested edits are currently taking very long to get reviewed, as many of their pending edits are of this variety. Another factor would be that reviewers are simply choosing to reject such edits rather than use one of the above workarounds, which means that those edits require two reviews rather than just one.

This complaint has existed for a long time, and I [previously posted about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310832/377214) but didn't make a feature request at the time as I figured such edits were rare and the workarounds were sufficient. However, I don't think those are the case today.

Can we please preferably have the old checkbox reinstated in the Improve Edit form (but unlike the pre-2014 one, have the rejected edit count toward an automatic suspension/flag and record an edit in the history to avoid license issues)? An alternative solution is to allow starting from the suggestion in the Reject and Edit form, rather than the current (non-suggested) revision, but that wouldn't address the above case of a reviewer changing their mind about the edit being helpful while they're making the edit.

Comment: Can you clarify re: the second bullet, are you saying that "reject and edit" doesn't count against the suggesting user's record in all cases, or that it doesn't if the hidden checkbox is unchecked, due to the legacy logic involved?

Comment: @zcoop98 It's the latter. I believe I clearly phrased this in the bullet, so it'd be nice to know what part of it implies it could be the former

Comment: Alrighty, that makes sense. I probably just wasn't in a clear enough headspace to parse it. Reading it now, I think the bullet is fairly clear, just maybe a bit too information dense for my brain fog at the moment.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog There's a potential issue with rejecting an edit, then basing an edit off it anyway. The original author of those edits isn't credited in the revision history.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 My main issue is with the edit being recorded as an approved edit and the editor getting 2 reputation. The new checkbox can be implemented to give the editor credit but not those things.