# 2 wrong edits and 7 days forbidden

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

About 10 days ago, I made some mistakes when I edited two tags, then I was forbidden to edit any tags, questions, answers, etc.

10 days ago, the system generated this error;

```
Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.
```

But today, the system generated the same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/9);

```
Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.
```

The days count never decreases. And I still can't do any [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Can you suggest me anything for solving this problem?

Comment: Yes, stop making bad edits! (j/k, I +1ed)

Comment: Same input, same output. It is called _time invariance_ :)

Comment: Why not just focus on answering questions for a while? Get your rep up enough and you lose the training wheels…

Comment: @Juan Just 2 mistake and i'm so sorry :)By the way, what is (j/k, l + 1ed) ??

Comment: @Wether :) But i think there is a problem in here right?

Comment: @Soner Sure. That is why you got 11 upvotes here

Comment: @Donal I always focus answering but when i see a bad formatting Q or A, i want to change right formatting. Like habit :)

Comment: @Soner: You're not the only one, but even so: _whoa there, cowboy!_ (Also, remember that there are many different valid formatting styles. Changing from one to another is not as likely to get approved as ensuring that a submission is in some style at all; changing like that isn't exactly respectful.)

Comment: @Donal I totaly agree with you. What i meant to say, is this a bug or something? Never decrease from 7 days? Am i wrong?

Comment: @Soner, as one who has rejected some of your edits in the past, i would like to say: make sure your edit adds **value** to the question. Don't just try to pick up on small inconsequential spelling or grammar mistakes. I'm not accusing you in particular, but my philosophy is to reject those edits as they add no value and can be by someone just looking for easy rep. (See this post: [Meaningless and annoying edit proposals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84228/meaningless-and-annoying-edit-proposals/84230#84230) ).

Comment: It meant that I was joking and that I upvoted

Comment: Should be fixed in 6 to 8 [lots of 7 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 20th of April was not the best of days for you.

You had 5 rejected edits in close succession, so ... the system auto banned you.

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34479
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34480
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34596
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34597
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34598
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/34599

The current banning code is even more lenient than it used to be, it will look at your ratio of accept / reject and account for it.

Looking through your history you have many good edits, it is just that you had a bad day and the system told you to slow down.

Comment: the problem is that he is suspended for 7 days, but its now 10 days later and the message still says come back in 7 days. And that shouldn't be right.

Comment: @Gamecat ... he was banned twice ... and was able to post suggested edits since his second ban expired