# I can't suggest an edit to another persons question or answers

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was able to suggest edit to another persons question or answer, until now even though it required approval by another trusted user. But now I am not even able to do it. Is it some change in policy of SO?

I can see only *retag, link, flag* labels. Is it only me who faces this situation or are there others?

Comment: May I suggest to **you** to use at least *some* capitals letters? ;)

Comment: Lol was in a hurry. wanted to know why. Sorry

Comment: I rejected two of your suggestions back in March 8, feel free to read my comments in each. In short: don't just **bold** every **second** word in a **post**. Don't put words into the author mouth. Don't change the meaning of posts.

Comment: how do i read your comments? n how do i know edit has been rejected?

Comment: Robit, [view your Activity tab, filtered by suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1155650/rohit?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). View each listed suggestion to see how it's been handled.

Comment: it just shows suggested edit and doesnt show any other results like comments or wheter it was approved or declined

Comment: Uh, you have to click on "suggested edit" to see how it was handled. And you get [this](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/216560), for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you've had a large (5 in quick succession) number of suggested edits rejected you are barred from suggesting any more for a while (7 days). This is [an automatic process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88741/2-wrong-edits-and-7-days-forbidden/93161#93161).

Checking your recent [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155650/rohit?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) I see a fair number that have been rejected. So this could well be the reason.

- To find out whether edit has been rejected or approved, [view your Activity tab, filtered by suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155650/rohit?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Click each listed suggestion to see how it's been handled:

  > [image]

Comment: Does it happen automatically and hence soon after a certain number is reached? For me it happened a couple of days later, if it even is the case. Does one (of one) rejected edit seem enough for that to happen? The 'edit' link stayed there for quite some time after, but when I tried to suggest a fix to a post with broken code markdown, the submission of the form gave an error. After refreshing I could not find the 'edit' link anymore. P.S. You've edited the answer, so 1 rejected edit cannot explain what I see, right?

Comment: @LevLevitsky - see the linked answer. I don't know the details and I would expect them to be kept vague. I know it's not necessarily consecutive edits and it might be a job that runs periodically which might explain the delay.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF, although the question you link to says that there's a system message telling that the user is banned from editing for a certain time. That differs from what is discussed here, although it can be that the 'displaying' policy changed, but the underlying mechanism is actually the same.

Comment: Funny, but it's there again. It was only gone for about 15 minutes.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - that might have been due to another suggested edit being pending.

Comment: the things is, I suggested an edit yesterday, according to my profile (seems like the day before to me, maybe a local time issue). The only thing that could happen today is this edit being rejected. So if I can't have more than one suggested edit pending, I should have been unable to edit since yesterday. If we assume that it's just the slow (once a day) routine that took them so long, then how did it give me my link back so soon? I know you said you didn't know the details, and I'm not so desperate to find the answer, because it all seems normal now. Just pure interest.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - no, not an edit of yours pending, but another suggested edit by another user pending **on the post** you are trying to edit.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks again.