# Can't edit posts of others

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I just tried to correct [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801992/android-exception-handling) because the code was not formatted properly. I could see the edit page, and some explanation that I have no privileges and it will be queued - so far so good. I corrected the indentation of the code part and when I clicked `Save changes` I got to a page saying that the page I was looking for wasn't found, and gave me some options on how to search. This happened to me also a few days ago, but I didn't report it.

Comment: Your link goes to your own answer (deleted by yourself), which post do you mean?

Comment: corrected, I deleted it because I thought that maybe then I can again see the edit link (that for some reason disappeared), and many others gave the same answer.

Comment: did you check whether you are [barred from suggesting due to rejected edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125597/165773)?

Comment: @gnat I never actually sent suggestions since it always says page not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that there was a pending edit on the post at the time.

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/224765) was approved *after* you posted this question.

Comment: So there can't be 2 pending edit suggestions? And I know my suggestion wasn't send because it said that the page is not found. :-\

Comment: @Martin - that's right.