# Why are my edits are not visible?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have made several edits in last 2 days but none of them seem to be appearing, except the retags.

At one stage, I even got an error saying my edits were rejected and I should try after 7 days.

Can anyone tell me what this means and why I am seeing this error?

Answer (score 7):

Since you have less than 2000 reputation on Stack Overflow, you do not have full edit privileges. When you try to edit a post, you should see the following notification:

> You do not have [edit privileges](http://www.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

Thus, the reason you aren't seeing your edits is probably because they were rejected by other users. And if you have too many edits rejected, you will be [temporarily banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84228/meaningless-and-annoying-edit-proposals/84230#84230) from suggesting any more edits. That's what the message you're getting now is telling you: you need to wait 7 days before you will be allowed to suggest any more edits.

However, retagging a question only [requires 500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions), so you have full privileges for that on SO. Your edits don't have to be approved by other users, and they show up immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 7 days is a big penalty! ;-). Is there a way out?

Comment: @Nilesh: No, there's no way out. [Some have complained](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91323/why-is-the-ban-for-too-many-rejected-edits-so-lengthy) that the ban is too long, but they didn't have very much success in the community. ;-) But that's okay, you can still use the site in plenty of constructive ways without edit privileges. And in 7 days, you'll get them back and can try again.

Comment: Please look at follow up question here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91796/why-should-the-edit-link-be-visible-at-all

Answer (score 0):

Until you have [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), the edits are only visible if two users approved it. But they are rejected if two users rejected it. I can see no edit suggestions of you in the list, so they are probably rejected.