# Why should the edit link be visible at all?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits

Following up from this question and its answer([Why my edits are not visible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91766/why-are-my-edits-are-not-visible)), Why should the edit link be visible at all if I am being banned from making one?

The current user experience is horrible with no notification that I am not allowed to edit because I am virtually serving a ban! It just allows me to edit and upon save comes back to original question.

Comment: I think people should be kind enough to leave a comment when they downvote! They should expect the recepients of the downvotes to be mature. Otherwise an important perspective is lost.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta mean something different than they do on Stack Overflow. In particular, they indicate **disagreement**, especially when you tag your question `feature-request`. The 2 people that have downvoted so far simply think that the edit link should be visible, regardless of banishment.

Comment: @Cody Gray: They can disagree by all means - but what stops them from leaving a nice comment explaining their perspective?

Comment: Nothing at all. However, I suspect they upvoted one of the existing answers because it already makes the case for their perspective. No reason to add another comment.

Comment: I agree with you that it would be nice if upon hitting "edit" you'd get a message explaining why your aren't allowed to edit.

Answer (score 11):

I imagine that this wouldn't be much different than [not showing the Ask and Answer options for suspended users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91636/hide-ask-question-button-and-answer-section), which was declined. Users who get blocked represent a very small population, and furthermore are in that population for creating problems for the Community. So improving their user experience is both extremely low priority, and unusual in its own right.

But I also agree with [Kop's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91636/hide-ask-question-button-and-answer-section/91639#91639), which I'll quote the relevant portion here.

> It would be more unhelpful than helpful. Suspended users will be searching for the button but they won't find it; they will assume maybe it was moved or maybe they forgot where it is, and this will lead to questions via meta or emails, etc.
>
> I believe it's important that the button is still there and that, when clicked, tells you that you are banned.

Which I agree with. If the edit link were not visible, how would you have learned that you were blocked in the first place?

Comment: That's the problem - as of today it doesn't tell me on click that I am banned. It just comes back to original question w/o any edits and "NO" message.

Comment: BTW its a harsh statement that banned users were creating problems for the community! That could be your perspective and there could be genuine users who got victimized!

Comment: @Nilesh I might suggest making that a feature request (though it sounds like something that might've already been suggested, so please search first). And yes, it may be a harsh statement - but that's technically what blocking is for - it's to prevent people who have been stirring up trouble from continuing to do so. I could phrase it as "generally are in that population for [...]", but honestly, the reasons for blocking kinda figure into why it's such a low priority to improve the user experience.

Answer (score 3):

It is not worth making many UI modifications for users who are on a ban because:

- There are very few
- If they are on a ban, then the community is not happy with them and is not a fan of making life easier for the banned users.

Comment: I agree that there might be few users. However, think about this its a user experience issue! And that kind of rude user experience can cause StackOverflow to lose few genuine banned users.