# Is there an overall maximum editing for members?

Tags: support, edits

I have been able to edit `SO` posts which I thought needed little changes to make the question stand out. Within the last few days, I have not been able to see the edit link to amend other member's posts.

All I can think of is that someone with a huge reputation has decided to block me from doing this, unless there is a maximum number of edits one can make in `SO`, if so can someone point me to this reference please.

Comment: What is your SO rep? Do you have to suggest edits or do you have full edit rights?

Comment: I was having suggest edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that a lot of your suggested edits were rejected. If that happens you can't suggest edits for a while.

If you find a post where an edit you suggested was accepted, go to the edit history of that post and click the suggested link you will see a summary of how many edits were approved and how many were rejected.

Comment: See also [Should tiny edit be accepted or rejected in review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review) - perhaps your edits, while perhaps valid, are relatively trivial?