# Correcting a single typo

Tags: discussion, edits

If a great answer is marred by a single typo, is it worthwhile to perfect the answer by fixing that one error? [In Defense of Editing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) seems to say yes, but two editors rejected my suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/190367

Comment: I think that typo should be corrected

Comment: IMO you changed the wrong identifier. You should have changed the second `name` to `firstName`, so the field name, and variable name are the same.

Comment: hmm since he mentions "name" earlier, perhaps it should really be `name`.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: That was actually what I was going to do at first -- except that Eric uses "name" everywhere else in his post, in the prose before and after the code fragment.

Comment: See [Should tiny edits be accepted or rejected in review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is more a case of the reviewer not looking through the edit to see why this specific typo being fixed is important to the post. In the following line, he does use `where resident.FirstName == name`, so changing `firstName` to just `name` would be more important in making the code flow together. However, the average reviewer just sees that you modified one word, and when the word modified is in a code block, the average reviewer will also think it's an invalid edit.

So now you have reviewers thinking you only fixed a typo (as per your message). They see the one tiny fix and immediately assume it's either too minor or invalid. I think a better thing for you would have been to explain **why** this typo needed to be fixed in the message, rather than just saying "fixed a typo" which isn't very descriptive.

You'll always have reviewers who don't care enough to read the context of the post being edited. You can always just submit the edit again. I'll keep an eye out for it if you do.

Answer (score 11):

I do that all the time.

Good answers that have a small typo should be fixed - whether it is in code or not.

Comment: @Juan - Good man, fixing that typo I left on purpose ;)

Comment: One difference is that you're a high rep user, and you don't need your edits reviewed. The rule against minor edits only applies to low rep users.

Comment: @code correct, philosophy being, low rep users need to *earn* the time they're asking for in peer review of their edits ..

Answer (score 6):

If it were just a normal typo in prose, rejecting the edit would be understandable. Low reputation users are discouraged from minor edits, due to the review work involved.

A variable called `name` is an essential part of the answer, however, so your edit was a worthwhile improvement.

I went ahead and edited it myself again.

Comment: Eric typically writes such perfect answers that I was confused (for a few seconds) when I saw `firstName`. I thought I'd missed something.