# Flag a user as "serial minor editor"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, serial-edits

It seems a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3714/kaiz-net?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has become a "serial minor editor". Checking his reputation gives a good overview of his activity. I have seen this [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits) which is a little ambivalent:

- accept minor edits if they make sense;
- don't let a user to pollute the first page of reviews with 20 times the same edit.

In this instance, the user seems to have run a search on "formating" and replaced all the posts he found with "formatting". It doesn't seem to add much value. When I found the first edit I actually appoved it. But then I realised there were at least 10 more and I rejected the others as too minor + one custom reject inviting the user to make more substantial edits.

Is there a way to flag a user as a "serial minor editor"?

**EDIT**

Would it make sense in such a case to use the "Improve" button and accept the change as proposed or improve if relevant?

Comment: +1 There are users who are well over 1K rep only by such kind of edits; I find it annoying, especially (and it happens often) when there are other mistakes in the whole post but they don't care and just edit the mispelled word they were after. It looks unfair to me, but in other MSO threads I saw many agreed on this kind of behaviour, highlighting the positive contribution of a single mispelled word in the overall post quality.

Comment: Here is the correct way to fix this "problem": http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92989/167500

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez to help my guilty conscience, I went back to the posts and corrected the spelling mistakes.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I disagree with that answer and I'm sure many others do

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply reject his edits.

Once you reject enough he will be banned from editing for a while.

Comment: But will he be informed why?

Comment: @TomWijsman - If he checks his summary he'll see why each edit was rejected.

Comment: And is there something that tells that to him?

Comment: @TomWijsman: the rejection reason is visible on all rejected edits. (Too minor is one of the baked reasons.)

Comment: @TomWijsman I've been once banned from editing. I don't recall UI details (it was too long ago) but I remember it was _very easy_ to notice and to figure why.

Comment: @Mat: I'm not talking about the edit reason, I'm talking about that it is not told to the visitors that there is an edit summary for them to check. A comment to remind the user can do a lot...

Comment: I discovered a serial minor editor. He removed the tag "Homework". After rejecting about 40 times my reject votes were used up. But he continued... and has now about 20 more edits accepted by others...