# Approving edits for "solved" questions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should tiny edits be accepted or rejected in review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review)
>   [An alert to serial minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits)

Over the course of the past two weeks the user [Zachary Schuessler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060207/zachary-schuessler) has proposed a LOT of suggested edits, almost (if not all) of which have been taking threads with the word "solved" in the title and removing it.  It seems pretty clear that he has simply done a search for the word "solved", and is editing it out of the title of all of the search results.

Most all of these suggestions are being approved in the edit queue.  (His current record is 58 approved and 9 rejected at the time of this posting.)  In my mind most of these edits should be rejected as "too minor".  I have looked at a lot of the questions, and almost every single one of them needs significant re-work to be a good question, and the only change this user is ever making is to remove "solved" from the title.

If nothing else, one major problem that most of these threads have is that the answer is posted in the question itself.,  Occasionally this is done in place of the question itself.  It is my understanding that the question needs to be broken up into that which is actually asking the question, and the part which is answering that question.  The answer section should be posted as an answer to that question (as the community wiki if the OP can't be brought back to post it as the answer).

In addition to often not being in the proper Q/A format, many of the questions are also poorly asked, have lots of spelling/grammar/formatting errors that should be cleaned up, etc.  No effort at all on the part of Zachary appears to have been made to even look for these issues, let alone fix them.  (Out of the maybe 25 or so of his suggested edits that I've seen anyway.)

I happened to be online and reviewing edits a few weeks back when he first put in a batch of several dozen of these requests, and I rejected a lot of them but saw them getting approved over time.  He has now added in quite a lot more now, and I imagine that he was encouraged by the fact that most of his previous requests of this nature were all approved.  At the time that I started writing this post the edit queue was only a handful of posts short of the max, so in my eyes supporting this type of behavior runs the risk of filling up the queue to the point that more significant edits can't be submitted.

So to actually ask a question: Am I being too strict here?  Is the little bit that he is contributing still worth accepting the edits?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/flag-a-user-as-serial-minor-editor

Comment: More or less canonically answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82873/131713).