# Is correcting a common misspelling too minor an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I've come across a fellow that is apparently trawling SO looking for the common "calender" misspelling and correcting instances to "calendar."

He often does *only* that... leaving things like "Thanks" and "Regards, JoeBob" in the questions.

Should edits such as his be rejected as too minor in review?

See also a proposed spelling edit on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430680/intent-filter-on-add-new-event-in-calender) that was closed as NARQ hours ago.

Comment: Wow, just looked at the guys rep page... 200 rep yesterday with about the same (low, imo) quality of edits.

Comment: I guess this is what happens when you give out gold badges for [hitting buttons like a blind man in a bowl full of peeled grapes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges#comment424717_147912).

Comment: @YannisRizos Correct. But Rejecting suggested edit will also get counted.

Comment: I'm getting sick of clicking reject only to be told the edit has already been approved!

Comment: I see there are some [revi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1) [ewers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/207616/relikd?tab=activity) who never reject an edit.

Comment: Sigh! http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/687660

Comment: I will typically fix the * remainder* of the post via the "improve" button but uncheck the "this edit was helpful", depriving the editor of their small rep gain. This is less than ideal as I lose the ability to tell the editor *why* I'm rejecting their edit.

Comment: This seems to happen from time to time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/flag-a-user-as-serial-minor-editor

Comment: I'll just leave this link here as reference because it is related and might be of interest (shameless self-promotion, too): [Too Minor rejection reason needs either to be reworded or removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116565/too-minor-rejection-reason-needs-either-to-be-reworded-or-removed)

Comment: Well, he's still going with it.  60+ rep so far today.  Hopefully he'll hit the edit rep cap soon and stop.

Comment: Well, it seems that he has started doing some real edits.

Comment: Shouldn't their be a moderator flag for site abuse? Not saying this is but if someone is excessively doing edits that could be improved, or if someone accepts everything that comes through then yea maybe..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If there are other things that could be "corrected," and the user is not doing that, the suggested edit is too minor, and it should be rejected.

The fact the misspelling is common is not a justification for making two users review the suggested edit; the time taken to review a suggested edit should be worth the edit. Approving such suggested edits would just give the message "do minor edits, and we will approve them," which IMO is not the message that should be given.

The message visible to any user who suggest an edit says:

> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: That was basically my opinion too.  Just wanted to make sure I was thinking about it properly.

Comment: I disagree.  Editing is an incremental process, and tacitly expecting anyone who edits a question or answer to fix everything that's wrong is nonsense.  If there are two spelling errors, and someone catches one, is the content not better for this?  We should be more appreciative of "micro-effort" like this.

Comment: @John Incremental process doesn't mean each user needs to edit a single word. The message given to who suggests an edit is clear about making an edit substantial.

Comment: @John: the majority of minor editors are lazy and out for rep. Either that or bored college English class TA's. I can find no other reasonable explanation for these edits...

Comment: @kiamlaluno Some people will have the time (on some given day) to do a thorough edit of a post, find 14 errors, tighten up all of the paragraphs.  Others will check SO three minutes before they leave, and find one spelling error in a post, and that's all they'll have time for because they have to catch their vanpool.  For others, these errors just "pop out" and they fix it, almost without losing their train of thought.  All of this to say that "please make them substantial" doesn't jive with "we welcome all constructive edits."  You welcome all constructive edits, or you don't.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'll fix a spelling/grammar error if I see it. I'm not out for the rep because I can edit without going through the approval process. If we have people who know English fixing up the content of the site, great! I like reading well-formed posts more than poorly-formed posts, don't you? Yet your comment about these people being "lazy" or "bored" shows no appreciation whatsoever for the expertise, and effort, that they bring to these sites.

Comment: @John: they don't *have* to edit the post. To be honest, I'd rather they ask and answer questions; that's far more important.

Comment: @John Nobody said everybody must find 14 errors, and fix them, to make a substantial edit; what it is a no is a single-word edit. Is editing a single word so urgent that cannot wait somebody who can edit every post? Then, there are different single-word edits. If the edit corrects a link that was returning a 404 error, and the correct link is not so easy to find, then I could accept a single-word edit. What I don't find acceptable is correcting _calender_ with _calendar_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's going to turn off well-meaning users. What you're saying, in essence, is this: "I see that you caught a misspelling, but I'm going to actively prevent you from seeing this change come to fruition, because I don't want to be bothered with this kind of work."

Comment: Yikes, there are *1,610* posts on SO that contain "calender."  I better get cracking. :)

Answer (score 27):

The main issue here (imho) is not the editor, but the 2K+ users that keep approving his extremely minor edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687212
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687210
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687204
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687202
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687184
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687188<sup>1</sup>
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687174
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687167
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687165
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687164
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687163
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/687154
- [etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525478/iioiooioo?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

I'm seeing some names repeating in there, and I think someone should give them a talking to about mindlessly approving extremely minor edits... Someone with a diamond attached to their name, perhaps?

<sub><sup>1</sup> my favourite, not only is it minor but it introduces a spelling mistake.</sub>

Comment: I'm in total agreement with you.  Unfortunately, I approved a couple before I caught on to what was happening and came here to inquire.  :p

Comment: @Barak Approving a couple, especially on new questions is no big deal, and an otherwise minor edit might be helpful if done minutes after the question was posted. But bumping old questions to the front page just to fix a single word is unacceptable...

Comment: could it be that careless approvers are just hunting for [Community Review badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) in suggested edits queue?

Comment: @gnat [Didn't I already say that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147946/is-correcting-a-common-mis-spelling-too-minor-an-edit/147948#comment424813_147946) ;P (linking to a comment in the same page is PITA, check my comment under the question)

Comment: The guy seems to have "internally" -> "internelly" in his list; I vaguely recall rejecting one with that same change. Funny.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the entire 'propose edits' system needs a think. To do a good job of reviewing edits, with 'too minor' in mind, requires a very careful read of the entire post. It's only human nature to see a fix to a conspicuous spello in the title and not see a mistake 'below the fold'. It's even easier to miss other edit-worthy issues.

Once I've gone to all the trouble to vet a spello correction, I find myself torn. It feels petty to click on 'too minor' if, in fact, I've found nothing else to fix. Yet, fixing one spelling error was a silly thing to do in the first place.

In short, reviewing is 10 times harder than making the edits in the first place, so the reviewers are doomed to play catch-up.

In my opinion, the rep threshold for any editing should go (back) up.

Comment: "rep threshold for any editing should go (back) up" +1 for that!

Comment: Yes . absolutely true.

Comment: I can't yet vote up but I would if I could. True to her master's purpose, the good mare Rosinante opposes giants disguised as spellos and thinkos. Well met!

Answer (score 6):

I want that guy to be banned from suggesting edits for a week for cooling down. It is a bit irritating, but acceptable if the edit really fixes the error. However, his edit introduces unnecessary new line characters that no one even bother to notice, for which I need to go to the post, do a rollback and edit myself (as the suggested edit is approved by 2 reviewers who don't take care to notice about the extra new lines). It seems that he is using some script to do the edit.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692687
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692664
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692644
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692578
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692571
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692501
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692449
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692413
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692392
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692367
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692019
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/692356

And that is barely 2 pages of his list of suggested edits. Those are more than enough to get him banned from editing with the low level of suggested edit queue exposure in the past, but they are mostly approved nowadays.

Comment: The newline addition makes me suspect it's a bot. And if so, that's grounds for banning, right?

Comment: I also have the same suspicion, but he might use some sort of script to edit the post then copy back. The annoying thing is that some people must follow behind him and clean up his **** that he left behind.