# More serial minor edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, serial-edits

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471203/real?tab=activity&sort=revisions) is searching for "Thanks & Regards" and removing it on each post he can find.

About serial minor editing: [An alert to serial minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits) and [Flag a user as "serial minor editor"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/flag-a-user-as-serial-minor-editor)

I've been seeing this a lot (searching for "Thanks & Regards," "aglorithm," "javasript," etc.) and it's been happening far too often.

What can the community do for this? (Other than reject his edits; the community is doing a horrible job at that, as you can see from his profile.)

(edit) I left a comment on one of his answers and got a *very* vague response: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952699/printing-a-string-of-text-into-multiple-lines-java/14952765#comment20999480_14952765)

Comment: See my question about him [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168191/well-here-we-go-again-another-serial-editor-for-pointless-things), and about a different one [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits).

Comment: I think his reply to your comment means that he is going to stop. If you want to give the user a link to backup why you are asking him to stop, you can use this one: [Does Stack Exchange have an official stance on users doing a large number of trivial edits to old questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165878/158605)

Comment: I used up all my rejects for the day rejecting his edit, but the two of us who saw what was going on were no match for the many robo-approvers.

Comment: @Linuxios Yep, me too :(

Comment: @Linuxios Me, too. I was trying to improve his edits and mark as not helpful. They were the definition of "too minor", leaving glaring issues unfixed.

Comment: @Linuxios I used all of mine as well or I would have jumped in to reject a few when I saw this.

Comment: So a single editor can use up all the reject votes from half a dozen reviewers, and the edits are still approved. Who said this system works?!

Comment: This user did have the best intentions in mind while editing, and thought he was doing the right thing by removing salutations, and he was. Some users simply don't grasp how collaborative the edit system is _because they lack the rep to see the other side of it_. I contacted the user, a very amicable fellow and I'm quite certain this won't be an issue going forward. In the future, there's little to be gained by calling out a specific user here on Meta when unfettered access to both the moderation and community team exists. Please, involve us first.

Comment: There is still some problem when getting 50+ reject votes in a short period of time doesn't send a signal to the editor. Some kind of automatic freeze of the edit privilege perhaps could be useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the state in the approval system, it will probably take a while before he gets enough rejects to ban him long enough to slow him down.  But judging from his edit comment, I think he believes he is doing the right thing and he is not just gaming the system for rep and badges.

Maybe a quick `@user` comment in one of the edits that has been approved that directs him to this question or to chat so someone can explain to him why his edits, while helpful, are not necessary the best for the site would be the first course of action.

Now if he continues after being explained the situation, then it is time to ask about what can be done to slow down his minor edits.

Comment: I'll go direct him here.

Comment: [I left a comment with a very vague response.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952699/printing-a-string-of-text-into-multiple-lines-java/14952765#comment20999480_14952765)

Comment: @Doorknob: I left him a link to this and a few other resources.

Comment: Hi @Doorknob I think removing user signature is correct as per stackoverflow. I never leave any vague response to you

Comment: You said stop editing and i stopped. If you will say i will never edit any post.

Comment: @RaisAlam It is not appropriate to *only* remove that when there are so many other issues with a post. That is the definition of the "too minor" edit reject reason.

Comment: @RaisAlam But you don't have to actively search for it. Improve more than one thing if you're going to edit a post.

Comment: *"I think he believes he is doing the right thing"*..well, he is getting confirmation each and every time these edits get accepted. The problem is not so much with this particular user, but with a failing review system.

Comment: Ok the thing I was sure should not be there I removed that.

Comment: @RaisAlam: Thank you for trying to help the community. In theory, it should be, it is just not a very valid edit reason in it's own right, especially when you just search for it.

Comment: @RaisAlam You didn't do harm. But next time please focus on the full post. Address all the issues in it. If you accidentally miss a minor issue, that can happen. But don't focus on a single item and forget about the rest.

Comment: @RaisAlam the problem isn't necessarily that you are doing it because you are correct, we dislike signature lines, but edits are supposed to be "substantial".  You are leaving many other problems in grammar, spelling, intro statements (like "Hi") in the posts as well.  You need to be thorough in your edits because reviewing takes time from the 3 (or more) people to approve/reject your edits.  In addition, ever edit you make bumps a question to the top of the front page, so when you make dozens of edits within a few minutes you are constantly bumping old questions to the top of the queue.

Comment: Ok I am summering= After a search "Thanks & Regards" and removing with edit is wrong. Am i Right ?

Comment: @RaisAlam If that is the only thing you remove, and you leave other problems in place, then yes, that's wrong.

Comment: @RaisAlam *Just* searching for, and removing, taglines, is wrong, yes--*particularly* when there are other things wrong with the post. Those edits should have been rejected as "too trivial".

Comment: @Bart, this supposes he recognises any other problems...

Comment: Ok from tomorrow I will try to find out grammar mistakes, formatting, and user signature. That would work or not ?

Comment: @Benjol That's why we have a review system...but well....

Comment: @RaisAlam - lets use [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1553168) as an example.  You left "Hai Friends".  The lack of real sentences (all of the phrases are just connected with "....".  Overuse of the word "Please" (and the "please .. please... please help me please" begging at the end too).  This question is a train wreck and needs significant fixing, but you left all of it to just remove the signature line.

Comment: @RaisAlam, and you could change all the 'i's to 'I's...

Comment: Ok I will mind it in future. I accept my mistake. Good night bye

Comment: @RaisAlam One of the problems with doing a large number of trivial edits, is you end up filling the "Active" question page will a bunch of old inactive questions, which makes it harder on the users who seek active posts to review or answer. From the page explaining the [Edit Privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit): *"Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.**"*