# Well, here we go again. Another serial editor for pointless things

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, clean-up

Well, here we are again. Another serial editor for something *completly* pointless. Someone did the brilliant query for the work "thanks" and is spamming the review queue and gaming reputation. And not fixing any other problems in some *very* problematic posts.

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1553134)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1553134)

Just look at the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471203/real?tab=activity&sort=revisions) for hundreds more.

Will someone please help start rejecting these edits as Too Minor? I'm out of reviews.

Comment: If you're going to close your own question as a duplicate, you might as well delete it I guess...

Comment: @Bart: True... We'll see. It'l serve to bring more attention to him.

Comment: Mwah, targeting a single user does not help a whole lot. We have a review system in place for a reason. If the reviews fail to do their job, you can't blame the user for making edits that are continuously positively evaluated.

Comment: @Bart: I know, but we need some sort of auto-sort edit alerter to make the robo-reviewers who look just enough to see if it's an audit look more. I'm going to post a feature request.