# Even more serial minor edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

Related:
[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164503/) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168190/)
[3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168191/) [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116509/)
[5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128514/)

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466082/arthur?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) has recently been spamming suggested edits, mostly on the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, and all they do is change code formatting to his own coding style, mainly 1. adding spaces before and after parenthesis, 2. changing indentation to the way that he likes it, 3. adding line breaks, and 4. adding spaces next to operators.

In fact, it appears that he is just copy/pasting code into his editor, hitting "format," and pasting it back into the question. He also makes language names bold, which is kinda useless.

Each of the Related questions that I put at the top of the post suggest either leaving a comment for him ([which I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506280/embeding-kannada-font-to-website/18506397#comment27304006_18506397)) or rejecting all the edits (which I did, until I ran out of reviews). The review queue has been shooting up sometimes above 50. Neither of these solutions are helping.

Now, here's the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). It would be great if one or more of these ideas were implemented:

- Maximum suggested edits per day
- Rate limiting on suggested edits
- Mod/10k tool that alerts to large amount of suggestions from a user
- Don't use up suggested edit reviews when reviewing the same user 5 or more times
- Allow overriding a suggested edit and making an edit of your own on a post
- Flag someone as a serial minor editor

I realize that some of these have already been requested. I just wanted to collect them all into one post and hopefully get one or more of them implemented. Serial minor editors are a big problem.

I also request that a mod look into this and somehow stop the flood of suggestions. It is becoming very annoying to have to wait for a suggestion to be reviewed before editing a post. Even more annoying now that I'm out of reviews!

Oh, and just in case you don't think this is a problem, I invite you to [scroll down this massive list of terribleness.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466082/arthur?tab=reputation) And the [28 pages of suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466082/arthur?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), which each contain 20 suggestions, for a grand total of 560 suggestions (!).

Comment: I also appear to have been [contacted by email](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3o7kE.png)...?

Comment: there's not already a maximum suggested edits per day??! Wow, that's one way to hit the rep limit...

Comment: Or: blame those who accept [minor/bad suggestions like these](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18559073/revisions). Rejections *should* put spammy editors in the penalty box for 7 days.

Comment: Also, is there a way to trick the system, it appears user has got +8 for some edits on a single answer (within space of a few min).

Comment: The real solution as @Arjan also mentioned would be to educate reviewers to reject such edits and soon enough the user will be blocked from suggesting further edits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd We've all realized that's impossible :/

Comment: Or just **stop giving reputation** for suggesting edits.

Comment: What the heck, *you* [approved this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2836538)?

Comment: @Arjan That was before I realized that he was spamming minor edits

Comment: ...but, even if that were the one and only edit they suggested, then why approve that? Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2836534)?

Comment: @Arjan Because that actually fixed all the problems in the post

Comment: I disagree: there was too little to be fixed, even if *all* was fixed, to bother reviewers. (I *think*; I don't do reviewing.)

Comment: @Arjan Meh, it made it more readable, and that's an improvement. If it improves everything there is to be improved, then I'll approve it.

Comment: I partially agree with @Arjan. Reputation awarding should function more like the editing badges. They shouldn't get reputation at all for retag-only edits, and they should only get reputation for their first edit to a single post.

Comment: @Doorknob: Of course those suggested edits didn't improve everything there was to be improved. The text is still a mess full of typos and missing punctuation/...

Comment: There is a [user with similar behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2063547/shahgholi-ardalan?tab=activity&sort=revisions) in the sql tag that has been going thru and formatting code and nothing else.  Their behavior was raised in [another post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195912/the-one-about-low-rep-suggested-edits-to-deleted-posts). The robo-reviewers have been approving the bad edits.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178147/automatically-queue-up-and-evenly-distribute-mass-edits?noredirect=1#comment938704_178147