# How to handle prolific "editor" of minor changes?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A user makes reasonable edits (I'd approve), yet has a consistent habit of breaking every paragraph into multiple one-sentence paragraphs. I'd reject this out-of-hand, but to-date see no reasonable way to communicate what I see as helpful vs edits that are minor and annoying to native English speakers.

I'm confident the community consensus will likely be to ignore this behaviour, but is there a way to help this editor improve their edits?

Comment: similar question, however, this does not cover those already with editing privileges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/flag-a-user-as-serial-minor-editor?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can @-reply an editor; if they consistently make these edits, and you have suggestions for them, then you are free to shoot a comment their way with your suggestions.

If you see these in the queue, you can improve them for formatting.

If you consistently see them from one user, you may comment to point their behavior out to them.

If you see a post which was edited in this fashion, feel free to edit it into a more readable state.

Comment: I tried @-commenting, the "auto-complete" wasn't picking up on the name so I assumed it wasn't going to "take".

Comment: @RichardSitze although there isn't autocomplete, it does notify. see comments on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits?rq=1

Comment: @RichardSitze See [How do comment @-replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) from the Meta FAQ

Comment: Also tried "rebuilding paragraphs" for a while (by Improving), but that got tiresome fast (no good way for me to "see" both the original I was aiming for with my edit to the intervening edit).

Comment: @Richard While it is nice if you do, it is not absolutely necessary to revise it, except in extreme cases. If you do need to revise it, then you don't necessarily need to go back to the original order; just whatever order makes sense.