# 1 character edits from 2k+ users

Tags: discussion, edits, too-minor

Sometimes I see edits by 2k+ users, where the only difference is an trailing `,` or an equivalent minor change.
Like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19764970/revisions).

[image]

- What drives experienced community members to make such minor edits?
- What steps should be taken in such a case? Simply rollback perhaps?

Comment: Well rollback seems bad because that just does another minor edit

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Yeah, that's a point, I haven't looked at it from this point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such users probably go for a shiny badge.

You could leave a @-comment to the users that such edits are not welcome since they push the questions in the active questions queue when they are actually not.

Comment: The solution is to have a [special handling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92989/167500) of trivial edits, removing reputation, badges advances and question bumps altogether.

Comment: Like the [Copy Editor](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor), that makes sense.

Thanks!

Does the pushing of questions in the active queue apply to rolling-back edits too?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez That would seem like a fairly good idea, the problem, i see is, that edits by 2k+ Users bypass the review queue which makes it quite hard to distinguish valid edits from invalid ones.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 yes rollback is an edit as well so it will push the question to the front.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thank you, that's good to know :)