# Increased Daily Limits With Increased Reputation

Tags: feature-request

It appears that the more accepted moderator flags you raise, the more moderator flags you are allowed to raise each day, so could other activities be made consistent with this?

For example:

- Could the allowed number of daily edits increase the more accepted edits you make?

Comment: Really those are three separate requests, and shouldn't be in a single post.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will amend and create some more. If I create 2 more questions are you sure they won't be closed as dupes of this one?

Comment: You should either delete this question, or change it so that you're asking one of those three things.  Once you remove two of them, you could post a question asking for each of them in separate questions.  As for the general case, there is no answer to that; each of these issues should be addressed individually, not as a group.  The commonality in "increasing limits" is only a tiny aspect of each of those proposed changes.

Comment: Just out of interest - why the down vote when I immediately edited it on request?

Comment: [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  It signifies they don't agree with your proposal.

Comment: @PeteCarter: this is already implemented.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Well, if you say that it's currently infinite, it doesn't get bigger as you edit more; it just stays at infinity, forever.

Answer (score 6):

When you reach 2,000 reputation there is no limit to the number of edits that you can make on others' posts, so I don't see a need for this.

Comment: You could then argue this is [tag:status-bydesign] or even [tag:status-completed] :)

Comment: @sixlettervariables I assume he's referring to the number of suggested edits for <2k users.  I believe there is a daily limit for it, although I'm not positive.

Answer (score 1):

From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) and [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701):

> We stop accepting edits in some occasions:
>
> - A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the last day. You are banned for a week.
> - We are out of empty slots in the queue.
> - There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.
> - You are not logged on and the post is less than 10 minutes old.

Since there is no per-user limit on the number of suggested edits, this feature request makes no sense, as there is no limit to increase.

[Here is a feature request asking that such a limit be implemented.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116636/limit-the-number-of-suggested-edits-that-a-user-can-make-in-a-day)