# Raise reputation cap as reputation increases

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It appears that the more accepted moderator flags you raise, the more moderator flags you are allowed to raise each day, so could other activities be made consistent with this?

For example:

- Could the reputation cap increase as your reputation grows, and it becomes evident you are not doing anything fraudulent? Maybe increase only within the certain tags where you have proved yourself?

This is a follow up to the question [Increased Daily Limits With Increased Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155200/increased-daily-limits-with-increased-reputation)

Comment: Yup. Finally, Jon Skeet will be able to freely overflow the system.

Comment: Reputation is not capped to prevent fraudulent behaviour. For one thing it's capped to make sure people still have a life besides SO.

Comment: @Bart, which they can then spend posting on meta.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Exactly. Or the Programmers SE. Or Code Golf. Or....

Comment: We're doomed from the start, aren't we?

Comment: We were doomed before we started. We might just as well enjoy ourselves at the same time.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157377/176533

Comment: @Bart See comment above. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> and it becomes evident you are not doing anything fraudulent?

That is **not at all** why we have a reputation cap. You should read up on [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)