# Review: more users control

Tags: feature-request, review

Sometimes, when reviewing certain threads (for example, 'Suggested edits') I notice that there are series of edits from user (usually, low-rep.) with very minor changes. It's obvious that it is an attempt to increase reputation with such kind of edits - and it's not difficult to reject with `too minor` reason for me.

But I think such edits are not useful for SO (and, as an addition, this causes load to reviewers) - and, therefore, it will be useful to restrict users from suggesting edits for certain period if they have too many rejected edits already (for example, If user has 10 rejected edits today, next edit he would be able to suggest only after 24 hours)

Should we have such functionality? Same is to other review threads, I think. Something similar is discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything) - but it's different in my opinion.

**Edit**
[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits) is very similar discussion - my point is still different, may be - because I think automatic restriction (not only mod. involvement) will be quicker. Or may be such functionality already exists?

Comment: Not sure I 100% agree with the "lots of minor edits" problem, but temporary edit bans for a lot of rejected edits sounds sensible to me (assuming there is no such rule in place already?) so I'm +1 on the general idea.

Comment: @DavidX.Random 'lots of minor edits', actually, is a sample, yes. That may be other edits - rejected by some reasons. Users should care that their edits were rejected.

Comment: @KateGregory thanks, I'll update (there is very similar discussion, however, the difference in my suggestion is that I think it should be automatic system, not only mod. involved)

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, this functionality already exists.  If a user has too many rejected edits, they will be banned from editing for 7 days

Comment: @psubsee2003 is it? Hm.. I did not know that. Where can I read about that?

Comment: See the top answer on the duplicate I marked

Comment: @psubsee2003, no, not exactly what I've mean. My point is - where can I read about SO functionality (like I've described in question) - so to avoid duplicate topics creation in future

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo ah, sorry.  Well, everything on the [meta-tag:faq] would be a start, but the rest you have to do just by searching.

Comment: Sometimes minor edit is welcome, for example perfect post with a small typo. They should not be blocked.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo also [meta-tag:faq-proposed] can be helpful

Comment: @psubsee2003 ok then. Thank you - that answers both of my questions.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo but ShaWizDowArd is correct.  Sometimes small edits are important however, the system also blocks most minor suggested edits by requiring them to be at least 6 characters.  So the ones that you see when reviewing posts are already more than 6 characters.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree with that, my point is about obvious case of abusing editing system, of cause

Comment: The real problem is that the edit review process is particularly flawed with inconsistent (perception) of guidelines, ie. is it ok to remove `Thanks`, (when) is it ok to just edit tags, is it ok to format code, etc. Second, while I realize an edit takes at least three reviewers, the suggested edits queue is rarely above ten items, which means that it isn't really seeing enough edits. And as has been mentioned, an automatic ban should already be in place.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo the idea of someone making numerous changes for rep gain has been discussed before and in the end, I don't think you can do much about it.  Limiting the number of [suggested edits per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116636/182513) has been proposed.  But ultimately, the most rep someone can get from editing is 1000, which means they still need to earn 1000 rep to get any of the important privileges (