# When editing, is it appropriate to rewrite "codes" as "code"?

Tags: discussion, edits

When editing is it appropriate to rewrite "The **codes** with the problem ..." to "The **code** with the problem ..."?

In other words, is the term "code" a *mass noun* when used to describe text in a programming language.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun):

> In linguistics, a mass noun (also uncountable noun or non-count noun) is a noun that refers to some entity as an undifferentiated unit rather than as something with discrete subsets.
>
> ...
>
> In English (and in many other languages), there is a tendency for nouns referring to liquids (water, juice), powders (sugar, sand), or substances (metal, wood) to be used in mass syntax, and for nouns referring to objects or people to be count nouns.
>
> ...
>
> Consider, for example cutlery: If one collection of cutlery is combined with another, we still have "cutlery." Similarly, if water is added to water, we still have "water." But if a chair is added to another, we don't have "a chair," but rather two chairs. Thus the nouns "cutlery" and "water" have cumulative reference, while the expression "a chair" does not.

Comment: Might be more suited to http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Is it wrong to use the word “codes” in a programming context?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context) mostly answers your question; if you're asking whether or not its worth correcting this on Stack Overflow, then Lix provides a good answer below.

Comment: **Yes!** *Please* do this. "Code" is indeed a mass noun, and it's extremely irritating to see it misused all over the place.

Comment: Pluralization often gets lost in translation, especially when your native language uses plurals a lot differently than English (there is no such thing as a mass noun in Tagalog, for instance). I am often asked for help with 'codes', and I die a little every time that happens. It's also common to say 'cereals' instead of 'cereal', or 'I have colds' instead of 'I have a cold', or 'I have rashes' instead of 'A rash', and I'll end this rant on that :)

Comment: I don't think "code" is always a mass noun. In a crypto context "codes" can be fine.

Comment: In some cases it might even be correct for source code. In particular when referring to several separate implementations.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I was referring specifically to the "text in a programming language" sense and not to the "output of an encoder" sense.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I think I agree.  [Search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+the+codes) suggest that "confirmation codes" and "QR codes" are two kinds of countable codes that are commonly used in SO questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How you make edits is completely up to you.  If you feel it is an improvement then submit your edit.  If the community is particularly displeased with your edit it can be rolled back to a previous version.
Note that such minor changes are generally OK - its just like correcting a spelling mistake or adding capital letters to a post that is burning your eyes and itching at your fingers...
<sub>You all know these :P Happens to the best of us ;)</sub>

However... If you start to make too many tiny edits all over - you might get on somebody's nerves :)

Comment: But please, try to edit other things *too*. If you're going all grammar police on a post, do it for the *entire* post. Make sure it makes complete sense, is well formed, all the spelling is correct, expand uncommon acronyms, etc, etc. Don't just edit the one thing and leave the rest for another edit. If this really is the *only* thing that needs editing, then by all means.

Comment: @a - very true...  Too often also a question gets edited (correctly) and the title is left untouched.

Comment: As for *"such minor changes are generally OK"*: in the case of *suggested* edits (in the peer review process), I disagree. In fact, there's a reject reason just for that. See also [Why can suggested edits be “too minor”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122923/why-can-suggested-edits-be-too-minor)

Comment: @ar - I don't think that anyone would reject one spelling mistake if it is the only thing in need of correcting.  Correcting `faecbook.com` to `facebook.com` when dealing with URL's is extremely minor - only 2 letters were changed.  However this is a crucial and *valid* correction.

Comment: @Lix: The point is that you should be fixing other things wrong with the post at the same time. If you leave other spelling or formatting mistakes, I'll reject that suggested edit. If there's honestly nothing else to fix, I'll approve it.

Comment: @c - yes I am agreeing with you and with Arjan.  If one is attempting to improve a post then one should review the **entire** post and make **all** the necessary edits.  However, if there is only one minor correction and that correction is a "make or break" issue - then I can't see someone rejecting it.

Answer (score 6):

If that was your **only** edit then I wouldn't bother. It may not be grammatically correct, but most of us can live with it. If you have an overwhelming urge to jump in and edit the question simply for that then you might have to consider that your inbuilt [Natural Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) [Parsing](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) module is not as tolerant as it could be. Or you might just have [OCD](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001926/).

But if there are other issues with the question then by all means fix it. Especially if you believe it could impact on the searchability of the question. If I use the word `code` in my Google query then Google is pretty good at treating `code` and `codes` as synonymous (it will return results containing either word), but the SO search function doesn't - this can be a good reason for making an edit as minor as that.

Comment: Hmm yes, both of those things describe me... What to do now?

Comment: @Cody - edit away, have fun - once you've fixed one issue you will find another and the cycle will start again :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, please do change it to just 'code'. Every time I read a question with "the codes" in it I immediately think of this:
 http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx

...which in turn makes me less likely to answer the question!