# Why are minor improvements not encouraged?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, markdown, spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites)

The [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) says:

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
>   change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

I understand that questions and answers oftentimes need more than one fix, as [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122927/187928) suggested, but when there is only one thing to fix, why discourage an edit? Fixing a small typo can, in my opinion, substantially improve a question's or answer's quality.

Also, white spaces are not counted. Many times I see a question that is very unreadable because of poor code formatting, and only needs for some code to be indented. SO prevents me from submitting such an edit, asking me to edit some more, when it's just not necessary to do so.

Do you think it's fair to ask for this to be improved?

Comment: @random That question mentions nothing about white spaces being counted, so it's not an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: Here's part two then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119074/do-not-enforce-6-non-space-characters-suggested-edit-rule-for-changes-to-code-fo

Comment: Okay, I couldn't find one. Thanks, that does answer my question.

Comment: This should instead be a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged, which is an exact match.

Comment: @Hassan: the refusal to allow minor edits that clearly fix serious issues is a pet peeve of Jeff Atwood, and he's incredibly obstinate about it, as [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128537/150034) demonstrates.