# Do small title edits constitute trivial edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, trivial

Being a fairly new user something I don't seem to be able to locate is information on whether small edits to the title are considered as trivial edits. I see the usual recommendation when suggesting an edit is:

> Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.

I can see the logic in that for most cases, but for example I just read a question with a title containing "Andriod" which would be trivial in one way but also affect the ability of users to locate the question using both the site and external search engines. Would it be frowned upon to suggest an edit for those cases?

Comment: cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits/116555, and the related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116565/too-minor-rejection-reason-needs-either-to-be-reworded-or-removed/116580#116580

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The criteria I use to determine if an edit is too trivial is to look at the big picture; I look at the post as a whole. If a person only changed one character in the title, the first thing I do is review the rest of the post. If there are no other problems with the post, then the edit should significantly improve the post. In some cases, a spelling correction in 1 word could be considered substantial, so if it really does help, I'll approve the edit.

Now, if there are other issues with the post that the editor did not fix, then I lean more towards rejecting the edits, depending on how important I view the correction. If the post still contains massive grammatical and spelling errors, no paragraphs, and messy code, then I'll reject the edit, regardless of how important the title edit may have been. In some cases, I'll reject the edit and then just fix everything myself.

So for best results, if you edit a post to fix a problem, try to fix *all* of the problems. This will ensure that, when two people review your edit, there's a greater chance those two people will approve it. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: If an edit is approved, @Adinia, then you can leave a comment on the post that the user edited, using the same `@username` syntax in the comments. This might be more visible than the reject reason. I did just reject one of the most recent edits. While the title edit was valid, there were other issues in the post he should have fixed...

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do that also if I'll see a similar problem in the future. Indeed, the edits are valid, but he's not even correcting  all of that word occurrences in the post, only the title.

Comment: @jmort253: What if one just doesn't **notice** other issues, or notices it but isn't sure how exactly to fix it? Why does it **have** to be an "all-or-nothing"?

Comment: @Sarah - First, the goal isn't all or nothing. The goal is to make a *substantial* edit. If you miss one or two things but still make substantial corrections, that is still a good edit and should be approved.  If you miss a significant portion of the edit because you didn't notice, then spend time in meta learning about what to change. Look at other edits to see what approved edits look like. Improve your skills as an editor so that your edits provide value. Hope this helps.

Comment: I still don't *entirely* agree with the policy, but I do better understand its rationale, thanks to you.

Answer (score 4):

It depends from the content of the post. If you are going to edit *Andriod* in the title, but not editing it in question text, then it is a trivial edit; the same is true when there are other things that could be edited from the post, and are not changed.
Certainly, the question title is important for who is looking for an answer to a question s/he has, but I would at least expect that who corrects a typo in the title corrects the same typo in the post text.

The system allows you to edit a single character in the title, though. If you would edit a single character in the question text, you would be reminded about editing at least X characters.

Answer (score 3):

As it is a key word for search engines, in this case I would correct it to Android. If the spelling mistake was in an unimportant word, such as:

> Do smal title edits constitute trivial edits?

I wouldn't necessarily bother unless I was also editing something else.