# Authoritative link to provide users in comments for minor edits

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

There is this [classic question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

This is in the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

> Edits are expected to be substantial

Now I am in discussion with another user:

> [image: Comments]

[This edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2653961).

Can we have an authoritative link to give to users regarding minor suggested edits. It would stop needless discussion and wasting of time.

---

*The issue here, is not this user in particular, but the whole minor edit debate*

**Whether the suggested edit is valid or not, it would be good to know either way.**

> [image]

---

*I have added images, as the question in this example is so badly downvoted, I would not be surprised if it is deleted by the owner, in which case links would be useless*

Comment: ok, I think I have this question sorted now.. there were a few comments under the question about many issues and I needed to sort out what was what.. *sigh*

Comment: [Review of minor suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78288/review-of-minor-suggested-edits)

Comment: @SamuelLiew still leaves it up in the air. I guess the definitive answer is to cease to care.

Comment: @Skippy in which case both of you had failed ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about lol... I'm confused

Comment: @Skippy I mean, both of you had cared deeply whether or not this kind of edits is too minor or not.

Comment: Granted, I would have improved the edit and accepted it. It's perhaps minor, but there is not much else to fix.

Comment: @Bart yes I think I need to stop worrying about it and just approve them, if the rest of the post looks ok, or skip them, if I find it such a psychic dilemma.. stupid question really

Comment: @JanDvorak you mean we both failed at ceasing to care.. I get it.. omg I'm really thick

Comment: @Skippy The threshold I apply is this: Does the edit solve a problem? Does it solve the far majority of the problems? If the answer to both of those is "yes", I'll usually accept it. Even if it's minor, it might not be too minor. If however I have to go in and spend more time editing than I think the suggester has, I'll reject it.

Comment: @Bart I think that is a very good answer.. can you post it as answer.. I think the yard stick could be, if I have to spend more time editing it, then it's no good on top of the other points

Comment: No need. Cody did it for me. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116565/too-minor-rejection-reason-needs-either-to-be-reworded-or-removed/116580#116580

Comment: @JoshCaswell good question and answers. ty

Comment: @ flaggers. please vote to close on this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116565/too-minor-rejection-reason-needs-either-to-be-reworded-or-removed as it is addressing the confusion between substantial and minor edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People keep asking for this, and I keep answering it, endlessly repeating myself. So I guess I won't this time, I'll just direct you to my previous answers:

- [Definitive line between minor and substantial edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186987/definitive-line-between-minor-and-substantial-edits/189450#189450)
- [Should I use suggested edits to add tags, or is that too minor a change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191842/should-i-use-suggested-edits-to-add-tags-or-is-that-too-minor-a-change/191846#191846)
- [Minor edit of an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190102/minor-edit-of-an-old-question/190103#190103)

To justify posting this parade of links as an answer, I'll speak briefly about [the specific edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2653961) you mention. Personally, I think this edit is perfectly valid. Like I said in one of the above-linked answers, we have a clear policy against greetings and salutations in posts, and people are encouraged to review them. That's exactly what this person did, and since they linked you to the same Meta discussion, they obviously know it.

Now, there are a couple of other minor edits that I would have made at the same time, all of which revolve around the addition of periods, commas, question marks, and other required punctation to the sentence in the question body. I suppose that is why you rejected this as "too minor", because they failed to make these changes? So I'll ask you: **why didn't you click "Improve"** and make these additional corrections yourself? That's what I would have done. English is probably not this person's native language. They may not have noticed these problems, or they may have been unsure of how to fix them. But they did fix what they knew how to fix, and it was a clear, positive improvement.

By rejecting this edit, you haven't made the site any better. That signature is still there  when it should be removed. The other grammatical problems are still there, because no one fixed them. The point of reviewing suggested edits is to improve the site by polishing one post at a time. It allows someone else to do most of the work, but it isn't an all-or-nothing proposition.

If you think the edit they've suggested is really quite pointless (or, like [Bart suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191927/authoritative-link-to-provide-users-in-comments-for-minor-edits/191934#comment597968_191927), you have to spend more time improving it than you think the editor put in in the first place), you could always uncheck the "this edit was useful" box. That still rejects the edit, but fixes the problem of a poor-quality post.

Granted, the question they're editing is *not a good question*. But I don't know how to fix it to make it into a good, on-topic question, so I wouldn't hold other editors to that standard either.

Comment: yes I agree Cody and wanted to improve it, the problem with making improvements when reviewing suggested edits, is the improvements need to be a certain length. Which is why I didn't click improve, I didn't think it would pass the min req to improve edit... another issue hey

Comment: I am going to use this answer as my link than you.. all I needed.. and if it gets enough upvotes, it will 'appear' more authoritative - which can be the illusion of older more voted on posts

Comment: @Skippy Then it looks like you'd need to change your opinion for it to align with this - as it seems to go against your mode, and heads in the right direction instead. And having something _'appear'_ authoritative makes it sound a somewhat biased in one favour when not actually carrying the consensus - I think this does, though, anyway, but I find your take a little weird.

Comment: @GrantThomas I better way to explain it is this.. I am accepting that I should have approved the edit and I had mistaken ideas about reviewing.. so that is why I hae changed my stance.

Comment: -1 you said you won't answer again this time, but you still did :D

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191927/authoritative-link-to-provide-users-in-comments-for-minor-edits/191934?noredirect=1#191934).

---

I am adding this answer as simple solution for reviewing suggested edits.

By asking this question:

**Does my review improve the site?**

If I am unable (for whatever reason) improve the suggested edit, but can see the edit has made an improvement to the post. Then accept it, and not have a continual debate over what is minor and follow the  principle that Stack Exchange is a [Community run Site built](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) on [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). It is our site and we are here, trying to make it the best we can.

Comment: true, but we also want to avoid needless bumps and edit wars over formatting.

Comment: @JanDvorak in what regard, it has been an issue I have not been able to resolve until now. for me, I am resolving, at least one person's conflict, my own, and it may help others Jan